# How to Schedule a Ruby Script

Tags: scripts, ruby, scheduled

I have a ruby script I'd like to execute every 5 minutes or so.  I have seen mention of cron tasks, but not in the context of executing Ruby.  I would like to know the steps necessary to execute the ruby script on a scheduled basis.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Scripts are scripts whether they be python, bash or ruby. Just make sure they are executable.

They are the same as steps listed [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2368/how-do-i-setup-cron-job).