# How do I encrypt my /tmp directory?

Tags: encryption, tmp

After reading [this question about how often tmp is cleared](https://askubuntu.com/questions/20783/how-is-the-tmp-directory-cleaned-up), it would be best for our setup if tmp is encrypted. How do I encrypt it?

My fstab looks like this:

```
proc            /proc           proc    nodev,noexec,nosuid 0       0
/dev/mapper/vg_doulos-root /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=205a1a54-7dfa-45a6-a7e3-4a7234b3a473 /boot           ext4    defaults        0   2
/dev/mapper/vg_doulos-home /home           ext4    defaults        0       2
/dev/mapper/vg_doulos-tmp /tmp            ext4    defaults        0       2
# swap was on /dev/sda2 during installation
#UUID=705e9f69-bf95-4d44-9119-c40076d10333 none            swap    sw              0  0
/dev/mapper/cryptswap1 none swap sw 0 0
```

crypttab:

```
# <target name> <source device>         <key file>      <options>
cryptswap1 /dev/sda2 /dev/urandom swap,cipher=aes-cbc-essiv:sha256
```

Is it sufficient to put something like this in crypttab?

`crypttmp /dev/mapper/vg_doulos-tmp /dev/urandom`

and then this to replace the tmp file entry in fstab?

`/dev/mapper/crypttmp /tmp ext4 defaults 0 2`

Comment: Just a question, why do you need to encrypt the /tmp folder?  There are other ways of dealing with it.

Comment: @Mitch What other ways do you suggest? Any others that address the problem of what happens if someone breaks in, cuts the power, and takes the machine? (I mean, clearly not everyone needs something this robust, but it seems like encrypting `/tmp` beats most alternatives, when it comes to privacy of the files it contains.)

Comment: @Eliah Kagan Maybe something like shredding  /tmp folder on shutdown.  So if someone does breaks in, cuts the power, takes the machine, that will simulate a shutdown.  So shredding would be good.

Comment: @Mitch If they cut the power, the machine doesn't shut down. It was on, and suddenly now it's off. Nothing gets shredded. Any cleartext in `/tmp` stays there and can be recovered quickly and trivially.

Comment: @Eliah Kagan Following the default Ubuntu install, wouldn`t /tmp  be configured as tmpfs which is a RAM disk. So the moment the machine is off in any way, it should be gone.

Comment: @Mitch No, I don't think so. My Ubuntu 12.04 system has `/run`, `/run/lock`, and `/run/shm` listed as `tmpfs` filesystems (when I run `mount`). `/tmp` itself is just part of the `/` filesystem (i.e., when I run `mount | grep /tmp`, I get no output). Of course, if you *did* have `/tmp` configured as a `tmpfs` ramdisk, then you wouldn't have to shred it either. (Actually, there are exploits to read from RAM pulled from a computer that was recently on. But protecting against that sort of attack involves mainly an increase in *physical* security.)

Comment: Then again, my Ubuntu system is upgraded from previous releases. Is `/tmp` a `tmpfs` ramdisk on your machine(s)?

Comment: @Mitch EliahKagan describes exactly why I want to encrypt /tmp. On CentOS 6.2 I found that /tmp didn't delete all the files between reboots; I assumed that Ubuntu was this way as well. I can try to verify your statement about /tmp being wiped between shutdowns.

Comment: /tmp does get wiped between shutdowns...

Comment: My suggested solution doesn't work. Any other solutions? I get stopped at boot and have to manually skip mounting /tmp.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct incantation in crypttab should look like this:

```
crypttmp /dev/mapper/vg_doulos-tmp /dev/urandom precheck=/bin/true,tmp,size=256,hash=sha256,cipher=aes-cbc-essiv:sha256
```

The most important part was the `precheck=/bin/true`. The reason why /tmp wasn't mounting was that cryptsetup was failing due to a precheck. The precheck noticed that the LVM partition was formatted for `ext4` and refused to continue.

The fstab entry should look like this:

`/dev/mapper/crypttmp /tmp ext4 defaults 0 2`

Answer (score 2):

Starting with Avery's answer, (on Ubuntu 12.04) I had to specify the filesystem type with "tmp=ext4" to get it to work:

/etc/cryptsetup:

```
crypttmp /dev/sdb /dev/urandom precheck=/bin/true,tmp=ext4,size=256,hash=sha256,cipher=aes-cbc-essiv:sha256
```

/etc/fstab:

```
/dev/mapper/crypttmp /tmp ext4 noatime 0 2
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your right it should be enough to add
in crypttab:

```
crypttmp  /dev/mapper/vg_doulos-tmp  /dev/urandom  tmp
```

and in fstab:

```
/dev/mapper/crypttmp  /tmp  ext4  defaults  0  0
```

Greets

Comment: This doesn't work. :( I think it might be because `/dev/mapper/vg_doulos-tmp` is already in `/dev/mapper` and I'm trying to create another item there.

Comment: why you have it twice ?

Comment: I don't have it twice. I was just hypothesizing, but I don't think my guess is correct either. Here's what my fstab and crypttab look like: http://pastebin.com/GjsfewRR

Comment: I ran `cryptdisks_start crypttmp` and the output was: `* crypttmp: the precheck for '/dev/mapper/vg_doulos-tmp' failed:  - The device /dev/mapper/vg_doulos-tmp contains a filesystem type ext4.` Any ideas how to fix this? I think the boot process is choking on this.

Comment: try : /dev/mapper/crypttmp  /tmp  ext2  defaults  0  0