# Lost a saved gedit file

Tags: files, gedit, tmp

I saved a text file in gedit last night before shutting off my computer, and I remember what I named the file. When I turned on my computer this morning to load the file, I could not find it. I've searched for the file, and I've searched its content using`grep`, and I still have not found the file.

When I open gedit, in the "file" drop-down menu it lists my most recent files, and the filename of the missing file *is* there, however, when I select it, there is no text, it is empty. It says it is located in /tmp but I cannot find the file when I browse or search the filesystem. Please help me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the message in gedit you saved the file in the `/tmp` folder. Ubuntu as well as many other Linux distributions deletes *all* content in `/tmp` on every reboot. This is a recommendation from the [Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard).

Sad to say if you don't have another backup copy, your original is lost.

If you want to keep the files in `/tmp` longer, this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/20787/236) describes how to set the value of `TMPTIME`.

Comment: I have no idea how or why I saved it in /tmp, but I guess it's gone now. I'll just have to be more careful about where I save my files.

Comment: It happens to the best of us.

Answer (score 3):

If you remember the "exact" filename(including character sensitivity), then do a `locate file_name` in console(eg. gnome-terminal).

**Note:** 1) `locate` will not return the file location if the filename is "File" and you do a `locate file`, but fine if you do a `locate ile`, I hope you got me.

2) *gedit* makes a copy of every file in the same location as it was saved with a `~` appended to the end of its filename. For eg. if you saved a file `file`, then a `file~` named file should exist unless you have explicity set it not to in `gedit`. So, there is a chance you may find your file.

Answer (score 1):

Someone correct me if I am wrong but I believe the tmp folder gets emptied when you reboot so you should not expect to find it there. However, if by some luck it is there then you should go to the command line and hit

```
cd /tmp
```

then

```
gedit filename &
```

to open. If the file was blank it is likely that the file was not there so you can check whether or not it exists in this folder by typing

```
ls -l
```

Comment: Yes, it seems like the document is gone now. I'm able to open the file with your method, but it's empty. I have no idea why it saved in /tmp, I'll just have to be more careful about where I save my documents.

Comment: try list -l to check what is in the /tmp folder (it will list all files present in whichever directory you are in) My method will create a file if it does not exist (I should have emphasised that as it may not have been all that clear) so it was probably not there if gedit opened with a black document.

Answer (score 0):

It might be too late now, but you could always try to recover the file with [PhotoRec](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec). Given that /tmp/ has undergone a fair number of write/delete cycles by now it's unlikely that you'll be able to recover your file, but not completely impossible.

PhotoRec is included in the [testdisk](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=testdisk) package.