# Is it possible to delete files in the /tmp directory once a certain directory size is exceeded?

Tags: tmp

According to [How is the /tmp directory cleaned up?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/20783/how-is-the-tmp-directory-cleaned-up/759048#759048), the `/tmp` directory is cleaned up using [tmpreaper](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/wily/man8/tmpreaper.8.html), which uses `cron` to schedule cleanups at fixed time intervals. However, I would instead like to enforce a certain maximum size of the `tmp` directory. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write a little script:

```sh
#
#      your maximum size of /tmp in kbytes
#
maxsize=1000
#
#      now get the actual size of /tmp in kbytes
#
tmpsize=$(du -ks /tmp|cut -f 1)
#
#      when maximum reached, clean up
#
if [ $tmpsize -ge $maxsize ]; then
    rm -r /tmp/*
fi
```

This should be run as root, in order to clean up files owned by other users (including root) as well.

Comment: What if my program just generated the temporary file a few seconds ago and is about to open it for reading? Shouldn't there be a time test in your script?

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix You can remove only files older than x days using `find /tmp -mtime +x -delete`. See  `man find` for more options. Of course, if there is a risk of deleting valuable data, you shouldn't run this script at all.