# How should /tmp be automatically cleaned in Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, tmp

In [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/20783/how-is-the-tmp-directory-cleaned-up), I see answers for pre-14.04, 14.04, 15.10 "and newer", and other information, but there is not an accepted answer for 16.04 specifically, which is what I want to determine.

Should I create a config file in [tmpfiles.d](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man5/tmpfiles.d.5.html), should I install [tmpreaper](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/tmpreaper), or is there a newer recommended solution?

Comment: Do you regularly shut down your computer or is it a server machine with a runtime of months in one go?

Comment: It's a server that almost never reboots.

Comment: And when should it be cleaned then? There's no telling what might might be safely deleted from `/tmp` in a running system.

Comment: There are now two answers (mine, just posted and an older one) in that post that both show that the `tmpfiles.d` is the newer solution and is certainly not outdated.

Comment: How am I supposed to know which answers are correct for 16.04? It seems reasonable to have a specific question for this with an accepted answer, if it's potentially different for every version.

Comment: I can edit my post to say, 15.10, 16.04, 16.10, 17.04, 17.10 and keep updating it for every release, but I don't see much benefit in doing so, and I certainly don't see why there should be a question for every single release in existence. Also, there's a reason why answers are allowed even after accepting - accepting only indicates that the answer helped the OP specifically. And how are you supposed to know? Comment under the answer - after all, comments are specifically for requesting clarification or improvements.