# 18.04.4 Delete a file on shutdown

Tags: bash, shutdown, reboot, rsync

I'd like to delete a lock file if I reboot or shutdown my Ubuntu 18.04.4.

I created "usr/local/sbin/delete_lock.sh" with

```
#!/bin/bash
lock="/home/sebastien/rsync.lock"
if [ -f "$lock" ];
rm $lock;
fi
```

and then another "/etc/systemd/system/run_on_shutdown.service":

```
[Unit]
Description=Delete lock file at shutdown - /etc/systemd/system/run_on_shutdown.service
DefaultDependencies=no
Before=shutdown.target halt.target
# If your script requires any mounted directories, add them below: 
RequiresMountsFor=/home

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/usr/local/sbin/delete_lock.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=halt.target shutdown.target
```

then I launch

```
sudo systemctl enable run_on_shutdown.service
```

And restart

Any idea why the rsync.lock file isn't deleted ?
Many thanks

Comment: your script is missing a `then`

Comment: I think it would be much more reliable to delete the file on startup - this would work in case of a power loss or a hard reboot.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The [base](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-6.html) for the `if` constructions in bash is:

```
if [expression];    
then    
code if 'expression' is true.    
fi
```

so you are indeed missing a `then`.

```
#!/bin/bash
lock="/home/sebastien/rsync.lock"
if [ -f "$lock" ];
then
rm $lock;
fi
```

Might I suggest something:

You are making this far too complicated.

Put the lock file in `/tmp/`. That directory is cleaned out on every reboot and is the ideal directory to put lock files without the need for you to anything extra.  See for instance [How is the /tmp directory cleaned up?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/20783/how-is-the-tmp-directory-cleaned-up)

This method also supports an extension from the content of `/etc/tmpfiles.d`. See [How is the /tmp directory cleaned up?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/20783/how-is-the-tmp-directory-cleaned-up/857154#857154)

Comment: Another way would be to use a cronjob, simply use @reboot, but the file would be deleted at startup then. If this is convenient to you, you could give that a try.

Comment: It's actually `if command;` not `if [expression];`. `[` is just a command. In fact it won't work without the spaces inside the `[]` because there's no `[-f` command.

Comment: I copied that from the official manual ;) Here: http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-6.html It is a method of formatting not actual code

Comment: @Rinzwind Actual official manual: [`if`](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/html_node/Conditional-Constructs.html#index-commands_002c-conditional)