# If `/tmp` is a symbolic link, it isn't wiped on reboot

Tags: server, 22.04, reboot, tmp

On Ubuntu Server 22.04, I have an SSD mounted on `/scratch`. I replaced `/tmp` with a symbolic link to `/scratch/tmp` so that temporary files are stored on the SSD:

```
$ ls -l /tmp
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 12 Jan 13 16:22 /tmp -> /scratch/tmp
```

This seems to work fine with one snag: the contents of `/tmp` are no longer deleted on a reboot, as I expect them to be. How can I make this happen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Temp files are cleaned in Ubuntu by `systemd-tmpfiles` and the related service `/lib/systemd/system/systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service`, and the configuration for said files can be configured inside `/etc/tmpfiles.d/*.conf` (also see [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/20783/how-is-the-tmp-directory-cleaned-up/983848#983848)).

To include the directory you describe, create a config file:

```
sudo touch /etc/tmpfiles.d/scratch-tmp.conf
```

And then include this content in it:

```
# Type  Path         Mode User Group Age Argument
  e     /scratch/tmp -    -    -     20m
```

The `e` type defines that this is a "marked" directory that already exists, but should be cleaned. An age setting of `20m` will clean all files more than 20 minutes old (see explanation below).

If the type is `d`, the directory will be created if it doesn't exist, and cleaned up on reboot and each day.

Be aware that the timer triggering the service (found at `/lib/systemd/system/systemd-tmpfiles-clean.timer`) is set to run 15 minutes *after* boot, so you won't see the actual effects at reboot until after 15 minutes uptime.

Please see the [manpage for `tmpfiles.d`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/man5/tmpfiles.d.5.html) for more information.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142386/discussion-on-answer-by-artur-meinild-if-tmp-is-a-symbolic-link-it-isnt-wip).