# What can I use to automate backups of Gmail?

Tags: backup, imap

I'd like to automate the process of locally backing up my Gmail account, and am looking for a solution that:

- can be scheduled to run in the background
- does not cause messages to be marked as read

What resources are available for doing this in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

[offlineimap](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/offlineimap) [image: Install offlineimap]
is a popular solution for this.

#### Enable IMAP in GMail

([Google's instructions](http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=77695))

1. Sign in to Gmail.
2. Click Settings at the top of any Gmail page.
3. Click Forwarding and POP/IMAP.
4. Select Enable IMAP.
5. Configure your IMAP client and click Save Changes.

#### Setup offlineimap

After you install it create a `.offlineimaprc`

```
[general]
accounts = GMail
maxsyncaccounts = 3

[Account GMail]
localrepository = Local
remoterepository = Remote
autorefresh = 10  #refresh every 10 minutes
quick = 5         #Quick-syncs do not update if the only changes were to IMAP flags

[Repository Local]
type = Maildir
localfolders = /whatever/directory

[Repository Remote]
type = IMAP
remotehost = imap.gmail.com
remoteuser = your_username@gmail.com
remotepass = your_password
ssl = yes
maxconnections = 1

#Setting realdelete = yes will Really Delete email from the server.
#Otherwise "deleting" a message will just remove any labels and 
#retain the message in the All Mail folder.
realdelete = no
```

Then you need to run offlineimap.

#### Automating offlineimap with cron

In some cases having offlineimap running all the time can consume large amounts of memory, especially if you have a large mailbox, so you can add an offlineimap check into cron to just check it and then exit, here's a daily backup:

```
 @daily offlineimap -u Noninteractive.Basic
```

- [How do I set up a Cron job?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2368/how-do-i-setup-cron-job)
- [cron](/questions/tagged/cron)

#### Backing up offlineimap

The files will be in whatever you define in the localfolders line as a [Maildir](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maildir). You can back this up using whatever backup method you use:

- [Comparison of backup tools](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2596/comparison-of-backup-tools)
- [backup](/questions/tagged/backup)

#### References

- http://www.enigmacurry.com/category/gmail/
- http://blog.nixternal.com/2010.10.18/offlineimap-and-byobu-hacks/
- https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/OfflineIMAP
- [Man Page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/maverick/en/man1/offlineimap.1.html)
- Fully documented offlineimaprc [configuration file](https://github.com/jgoerzen/offlineimap/blob/master/offlineimap.conf)

Answer (score 2):

An alternative would be to use `fetchmail`. fetchmail can use both pop3s and imap4s to access Google. There are online tutorials on how to configure.

Answer (score 0):

I have done some [research on HOW TO backup an IMAP account](http://en.altlinux.org/User%3aImz/research_on_HOW_TO_backup_an_IMAP_account) comparing different available tools w.r.t. a set of wanted features and concerns. As a result, I used `offlineimap`, as already suggested above. (My saved comparison still may be useful to see a bigger picture.) Also, I [summed up (answering a related question)](https://superuser.com/questions/286497/any-file-based-email-client-application/286561#286561) some points concerning the architecture of such a solution for backing up an IMAP account and storing it in Git.