# Is it possible to schedule the downloads required to upgrade?

Tags: upgrade, cron, scheduled

I'd like to upgrade from 10.10 to 11.04 but my ISP has a data-cap, limiting the amount I can download. Thankfully, traffic between 2am and 8am doesn't count towards this cap, but I'm seldom awake at 2am to kick the upgrade process off.

Is there a way I can schedule either the upgrade or the downloads required for the upgrade to run at a certain time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution is to download the installation CD and then use it as a local repository to perform the upgrade. Instructions are here:

[Upgrading Using the Alternate CD/DVD](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NattyUpgrades#Upgrading%20Using%20the%20Alternate%20CD/DVD)

If your ISP allows you to download via BitTorrent at night, you can schedule Transmission to download the CD only at night from within the Edit ▸ Preferences ▸ Speed menu.

Comment: Great, already have Transmission set up so this should be easy. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In general, you could download your updates with out installing them. Just become root, wait for 2am, and start downloading.

```
$ sudo bash
# sleep 5h
# apt-get dist-upgrade --download-only
```

You could [create a cron job](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2368/how-do-i-setup-cron-job) that executes the last command (especially for regular incremental updates). Then when you wake up, you can install the updates.

Unfortunately, the `do-release-upgrade` command (the [recommended way to upgrade](http://ubuntulinuxtipstricks.blogspot.com/2010/02/dist-upgrade-misnomer-confusion.html) to the next Ubuntu) [doesn't have a download-only option](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/update-manager/+bug/664534), so I'd stick with ændrük's CD download.

However, if you're feeling really adventurous, you could follow the [instructions for setting up commandline upgrade](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/ubuntu/upgrade) and then run `do-release-upgrade` after a sleep. **Note:** I'd be pretty wary of installing updates when you're not there to see what might go wrong.

Comment: 1) [`at`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/maverick/en/man1/at.1posix.html) would be more appropriate here. 2) `dist-upgrade` only alters dependency handling; it does not automatically upgrade to newer releases. Apt sources must be separately modified beforehand for this to result in a release upgrade.

Comment: Thanks for the answer (you'd get +1 but I'm too new for that:). I actually use `con-apt` for regular updates. I'm sure it just makes a cron job but its super easy from the users p.o.v.

Comment: I guess you mean `cron-apt`. I've never heard of that. Sounds easier than what I described : )