# How to upgrade ubuntu 14.04 to 16.04 offline

Tags: upgrade, offline

I want to upgrade ubuntu 14.04 to 16.04LTS offline on multiple systems in my organization. i want to know how can upgrade ubuntu offline in multiple systems.Please help me to upgarde ubuntu 16.04 offline.

Comment: You should probably add info on how many systems you're talking about (upgrading individually might be easier for few systems) and whether those computers are connected to a server from which you distribute updates via a network.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to download from the official page

http://www.ubuntu.com/download

the last version and install it to your devices, one-by-one.

Installation does not need internet connection. Once you download the last version, you can install offline on your machines. (But better to connect them, before or later, to update the system.)

Here's how you create a bootable USB in linux http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu

Comment: Is there any other way than bootable USB/CD?  I used a script that is referenced in this [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/54681/can-i-make-do-release-upgrade-only-download-packages-for-a-later-upgrade), but even with that, I saw that `do-release-upgrade` is downloading `471MB` or more. Like, check the state of the system (all the packages installed and then fetch them offline and have a `xenial.tar.gz` which can be uploaded and installed (_offline_) on other hosts