# How to automatically reconnect after a connection is dropped?

Tags: 11.10, network-manager

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Make Network Manager restart after dropped connection?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/71528/make-network-manager-restart-after-dropped-connection)

My problem is the same as in [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/71528/make-network-manager-restart-after-dropped-connection) but since the question was asked months ago and nobody seems to answer, I am asking it again. I use a USB Modem for connecting to internet. Unluckily my connection drops frequently.

Every time the connection drops, I have to take the modem out, reinsert it and wait to for two minutes before it shows up in the network applet.

If I manually disconnect then nothing wrong happens and the connection is listed in the applet.

Comment: Ankit, is it a data card type of USB, like Tata Photon? Not that I know the answer and my problem is still alive.

Comment: I have a similar problem but I'm using a USB plug-it, sort of like a mini antenna that gets its connection from the cell towers. I think it runs on 3G. Anyway, it drops from time to time, and I have to take it out from the port and wait for the device to be detected again. Restarting Network Manager does not seem to have the desired effect.

Comment: @vasa1 yes, mine is from BSNL.