# Wired connection not working (unplugged) help?

Tags: networking, ethernet

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Make Network Manager restart after dropped connection?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/71528/make-network-manager-restart-after-dropped-connection)

I configured the `pppoe` connection in network manager it works perfectly fine when i start my computer after some couple of hours/min the network gets disconnected. When i check the network manager it says wired connection unplugged so when i restart it works fine again.

Can anybody help because I dont want to restart my pc again and again .

Comment: does it work when you disable and enable network manager? Click the top right icon for networking (the "up and down arrows" icon), select `Enable Networking` to uncheck/disable it. Select Enable again to check/enable it.

Comment: no it does not work... i tried that too...

Comment: **(1)** Need more info :) When the internet goes down, open a terminal, run these commands: http://pastebin.com/h1fGQmu9 - Save the output of commands in a text file on your Desktop (and the contents of dmesg.log). Restart your pc to have a working connection, open your temporary file and paste the output in a new pastebin at www.pastebin.com **(2)** This might sound stupid, but try it if it's a desktop: Shut down your pc and turn off your router. Unplug from power source/socket (**important**), leave it for about 2 minutes. Reconnect/Power up everything and boot again.

Answer (score 0):

Please try these two solutions. Unfortunately I don't have a mobile broadband connection to try them out.

- http://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?t=229718#2

> Right-click on the NetworkManager applet in Gnome, and select Edit
>   Connections. Highlight "System eth0" and click Edit.
>
> Go to the IPv4
>   Settings tab Click the Routes button Make sure the checkbox "Use this
>   connection only for resources on its network" is CHECKED. Click OK to
>   save the setting.
>
> Then make sure that the checkbox is NOT checked for
>   "apply settings to all users", and click Apply.
>
> Otherwise, the setting
>   above cannot be changed by an ordinary non-root user (it won't save
>   the changes). Unchecking this allows the setting to be changed for the
>   logged in user and therefore everything will work.

- http://platonic.techfiz.info/2009/07/28/mobile-broadband-connection-via-networkmanager/

> Now, time to apply the trick.. In PPP settings tab, disable “Use
>   Point-Point Encryption (MPPE)” as follows.

Comment: even I don't have a mobile connection. It's a DSL (wired) connection: a cable that plugs into a telephone type socket. There's no intervening router or modem at my end

Comment: BTW i tried it didnt work internet completely stopped working