# Constant need to restart internet connection

Tags: networking, 20.04, network-manager, internet

I have to constantly restart NetworkManager (or run `sudo modprobe -r iwlwifi && sudo modprobe iwlwifi` - effects are indistinguishable) on both of my Ubuntu devices to deal with constant sudden losses of access to the internet when I'm connected to my home network. I even started keeping a dedicated terminal tab just to re-run `sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager` again and again.

**0)** All of the affected devices are running Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS.

**1)** I have a main router at home and a repeater in my bedroom (because, when the door is closed, the main router becomes unreachable to Some of my devices).

**2)** The main router offers a single 2G network, while the bedroom repeater repeats the main router both as a same-named 2G network and as a alt-named 5G network.

**3)** The problem I will describe has never happened to my Android phone, but it does happen to both my Ubuntu desktop computer and my Ubuntu laptop.

**4)** It makes no difference whether I connect to the router or the repeater or which one I'm closer to. Only the problem is considerably less frequent (hours vs minutes) when I'm connected to the main router (but it does still happen).

**5)** It makes no difference whether I connect to the repeater's 2G or its 5G.

**6)** The exact same pattern shows up when I connect to either the router or the repeater via Ethernet cable.

**7)** My internet provider has replaced the main router in the meantime since the pattern begun (for other reasons) and, essentially, nothing changed.

**8)** The problem doesn't happen to my Ubuntu notebook when it is connected to other networks (even when for many hours).

**9)** Restarting either the main router or the repeater or restarting the devices themselves all have the same observable effect as restarting the NetworkManager: internet connection is back for a while, but the pattern persists and soon i lose my connection to the internet again.

**10)** The loss of connection doesn't affect one device necessarily at the same time it affects another.

**11)** Changing the wifi adapter (I have 2 USB adapters) changes nothing.

**12)** Factory-resetting the repeater and minimally re-configuring it to repeat the main router also doesn't change the pattern.

**13)** Turning off the repeater doesn't zeroes the recurrence of the problem with the main router.

**14)** Both `systemctl` and `modprobe` methods show the same observable effects.

**15)** The connection to the network itself remains when the problem happens. Only thing affected is connection to the internet.

**16.1)** One device is is a i5 / 8gb RAM desktop PC with a 500W PSU and no power saving feature enabled at all, usually connected to the repeater via ethernet (but it doesn't matter, as tested and already detailed above).

**16.2)** The other device is a i7 / 16gb RAM Samsung X50 notebook, usually connected to the repeater via its internal wifi hardware (Intel Wireless-AC 9462) (but it also doesn't matter, as also tested and already detailed above). It may also be relevant to point that the problem persists on the notebook even with no peripherals connected (I'm aware that they may drain energy and affect wifi performance).

**17)** All that said, the problems manifests in the exact same way in both devices, and Only between them and my home networks (I connect my notebook to other networks almost daily without any problem, I also have 2 Android devices which have never been affected, and other people connect their own whatevers to my home networks and no one has ever mentioned any connectivity issue), so that Ubuntu 20.04.4 seems to be the only factor unifying the affected devices and excluding all the unaffected ones.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Make Network Manager restart after dropped connection?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/71528/make-network-manager-restart-after-dropped-connection)

Comment: What hardware are you running Ubuntu 20.04 on?  Have you maybe tried disabling power saving features on the USB ports, if you are using USB WiFi devices?  Are all affected systems the same hardware on them?  Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1434569/edit) your question with more details.

Comment: @Muzaffar actually not. my connection to the network remains.. and reconnecting changes nothing. Really the only things that work is the two command lines i mentioned, restarting the computer itself or restarting the router/repeater

Comment: @Terrance Done. But the details I have already given covered the fact that the hardware used to connect didn't change the pattern.

Comment: Hardware does matter.  USB devices are notorious for powering off and on in systems.  Especially with power saving functions.  Knowing the hardware can help in seeing if you actually have the correct driver installed.  My system has a RTL8168 chipset in it and Ubuntu loves to load the RTL8169 driver.  While it works, it is extremely flaky.  So, hardware is very important in this.

Comment: Your Intel Wireless-AC 9462 might require the exact driver version from Intel to work properly.  https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000005511/wireless.html

Comment: I'm a computer science graduate, but networking isn't really my favorite topic. That said, my suspicion is about something between Ubuntu's networking stuff and my home internet provider, as the problem Only happens with my home networks, Always happens in my home networks, Persists after changing the combinations of network hardware in multiple ways, Never happened with my Android devices, Only happens with my 2 Ubuntu devices and command lines are able to temporarily solve the problem

Comment: @Terrance I made it very clear that the exact same problem happens with my desktop PC connected via ethernet and that the problem never happened between my notebook and other networks.