# How to run a cron job using the sudo command

Tags: cron

Is it possible to run a [cron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) job which needs the [sudo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sudo) command?

Like:

```
 sudo rm somefile
```

Comment: Welcome Sayem Siam, Have a look at the answers to this question http://askubuntu.com/questions/2368/how-do-i-setup-cron-job.  as I think your question has been asked before here on AU

Comment: I am trying to execute sudo which needs password but how can i giv password from cron file

Comment: @sayemsiam you don't need to put sudo, just edit the root crontab.

Comment: See [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/797290).

Answer (score 368, accepted):

I won't get into how much this is a bad idea; simply put, running `sudo`in crontab requires your password to be stored somewhere in plaintext.

**It's a bad idea.**

---

The following is the preferred method of running administrative tasks through cron. **Since you don't really need to write `sudo` in the crontab, if you are modifying root's crontab.**

#### Use root's crontab

Run the following command:

```
sudo crontab -e
```

This opens up `root`'s crontab. `sudo` is not necessary to run your command in this context, since it'll be invoked as `root` anyway.

Therefore, you would simply append the following to root's crontab.

```
@hourly rm somefile
```

---

Now, if you *absolutely* want to be unsafe and take risks with your password, the following will run your command from your own crontab, and enter your password automatically when prompted by `sudo`.

Again, **this is not recommended**.

---

In your own crontab, write your command like so:

```
@hourly echo "password" | sudo -S rm somefile
```

The obvious disadvantage here is that, should anyone ever access your crontab, your password will be readable in plaintext.

**You shouldn't do this.**

Comment: Glad it works! Just be wary of any security holes you leave behind.. They might come back later to haunt you.

Comment: @SirCharlo Why use `root`'s user crontab instead of the systemwide crontab `/etc/crontab`?

Comment: @Elijah why not?

Comment: This answer misses the mark because it glosses over the subtleties available in your `sudoers` file, like sudo groups without a password requirement.

Comment: very very useful point, thanks for great help.

Comment: Root's crontab is the best solution, it's explicitly for commands that require sudo so I don't see why you would even want to put your password in clear text whatsoever.

Comment: "You should NOT do it" | -> Everyone search for this askubuntu post on how to do it

Answer (score 50):

If you are putting the script from one of the cron directories (`/etc/cron.*`) then you don't need to use sudo as that is running as root.

If you are using crontab, then you will want to use root's crontab. This will run it as root, and also not need sudo.

```
sudo crontab -e
```

Comment: I would also place the command in /etc/cron.hourly/something. That's what these directories are for.

Comment: No. You could put it in /etc/cron.SOMETHING/SCRIPT, but I wouldn't do both. Both would give roughly the same function, although using crontab you would have a bit more power over how often/when things run.

Comment: I should have made clear that I meant that as an alternative. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Run following command in terminal

```
sudo visudo
```

Added the following line to the end of the file:

```
vidyadhar  ALL= NOPASSWD: /bin/rm
```

In the above example vidyadhar is the username and it will not ask for password if you are running rm command through vidyadhar.

Comment: Hmm.. Then any malicious command, like `sudo rm -rf 'slash'` (**don't run that command**), run from that user, would require no password.. I don't know, it feels unsafe, no?

Comment: Ya i know it. Your approach is good. But I am using above approach for giving rights to other user to stop/start certain services.

Comment: This is an _extremely_ bad idea. Please don't do this.

Comment: Maybe `vidyadhar  ALL= NOPASSWD: /bin/rm somefile` would be more secure.

Comment: This is a terrible idea. You gave **blanket sudo permissions** to rm.  Instead, give sudo permissions to a script your comand, including rm or others in that script, make it executable, then give sudo permissions to that script.  `<username> ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /home/<username>/bin/<script>`, which would be much safer.

Comment: This is not "an extremely bad idea", please stop with the useless hyperbole. Obviously giving a user the same amount of power as root will make it just as dangerous as root. This is perfect for a dedicated backups user, or other user account whos access is as tightly controlled as root.

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes it is necessary for root to execute a command as a specific user of the system. For example, with borgbackup, it is common to have root check the warehouse using the borg user.
if the task must be executed once a day, we will use the /etc/cron.daily folder, like that:

```
# cat /etc/cron.daily/borgbackup_check

#!/bin/bash
sudo -u borg borg check /borgbackup >> /var/log/borgbackup.log
```

where "-u borg" is used take the identity of the borg user, "borg" is the borg command and "/borgbackup" is the wharehouse.

Answer (score 0):

Nobody mentioned having an executable script with setuid bit?  I can see where this might be a security vulnerability, too (don't cut yourself, sharp knives in this drawer, keep permissions tight), but feels less dicey than working in the root crontab.  For instance, I'd like to defrag/fstrim nightly or weekly even when I am not present.

Another alternative is to leave a script running in a loop, sleeping until the time is right, that you launch with sudo.