# MMV doesn't execute in bash script (only if run by CRON)

Tags: bash, permissions, cron, execute-command

this is my script "backup.sh":

```
#!/bin/bash


date=$(date +"%m-%d-%Y_%r")

mmv -r "uploads/temp/*" "#1\ '$date'"

mv /ftphome/uploads/temp/* /ftphome/uploads/arch/
```

My dir structure is like that:

```
dr-xr-xr-x 9 it2 it2 4096 Feb 29 12:09 arch
drwxrwxr-x 2 it2 it2 4096 Feb 29 12:09 temp
```

When I try to execute script from console all is working - as root, because otherwise I get an error "directory uploads/temp/  directory not allow writes" <- I set this permission on purpose.

Unfortunately when I'm try to start this script by corn, mmv command doesn't execute, and all files move to "arch" directory without suffix.

I was trying to change chmod permission to 777 for "temp" dir, but it doesn't help.
I edited crontab as root, so it should work as root (that info I read in this topic: [How to run a cron job using the sudo command](https://askubuntu.com/questions/173924/how-to-run-a-cron-job-using-the-sudo-command) ).

BTW, it is like i try to execute script by cron (every minute is for testing):

```
* * * * * /ftphome/backup.sh
```

Comment: You shouldn't rely on a relative path `uploads/temp/` for the source directory. You may need to use full paths for the commands as well e.g. `/usr/bin/mmv`. Also, `'$date'` will likely not be expanded because of the single quotes.

Comment: @steeldriver No, set PATH rather than using absolute paths to commands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `cd` to the correct directory first. Cron starts you off at `/`.

```
#!/bin/bash
date=$(date +"%Y-%m-%d_%r")

cd /ftphome || exit

mmv -r "uploads/temp/*" "#1\ '$date'"

mv /ftphome/uploads/temp/* /ftphome/uploads/arch/
```

On a side note, don't put `.sh` extension on a bash script. It's misleading since sh is not bash.