# How to avoid password request for sudo for crontab scripts?

Tags: command-line, bash, sudo, password, cron

I need that a new user could execute `sudo` without any request of password, because this user has in `crontab` a `.sh` that uses `sudo` for some commands.

I created a new user on my ubuntu server 16.04 x64

```
adduser my-user sudo
gpasswd -a my-user sudo
```

Then using `visuo` i added this line, based on [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/147241/execute-sudo-without-password)

```
my-user ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD : ALL
```

Then rebooted

After reboot I logged in using `my-user` and tried to do sudo clear, but it ask me the sudo password.

**NOTE**: I've added the crontab using `crontab -e my-user` so I suppose my script is executed as `my-user`. In fact, the crontabbed script crashes telling me in the log about a `sudo` request of password. I really need to execute the script in this way to be able to create file with `my-suer` as owner.

Please tell me if some steps/lines were not needed and how to make able `my-user` to execute `sudo` without password request.

Thanks

PS: I seen [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/7477/how-can-i-add-a-new-user-as-sudoer-using-the-command-line), but I'm not able to make it working so I need a more precise explanation, because my situation is different: i'm running a crontab script and I need it do not ask for sudo password

Comment: crontab scripts are supposed to be executed as root, they shouldn't need sudo

Comment: I've added the crontab using `crontab -e my-user` so I suppose my script is executed as `my-user`. In fact, the crontabbed script crashes telling me in the log about a `sudo` request of password

Comment: possible duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/questions/7477/how-can-i-add-a-new-user-as-sudoer-using-the-command-line there is also the /etc/sudoers

Comment: @Cloacker: I seen the question you point to, but I'm not able to make it working so I need a more precise explanation, because my situation is different: i'm running a crontab script and I need it do not ask for sudo password

Comment: I think the only way to do it is by previous config. try this other http://askubuntu.com/questions/147241/execute-sudo-without-password

Comment: I can't see any good reason to do this - if you need to schedule tasks that require elevated privileges to run, then put them in root's crontab (`sudo crontab -e`) instead of putting them in a user crontab with sudo inside.

Comment: Agreed with Serg and Steeldriver, although I did run into file ownership problems, e.g. when executing backups from root's `crontab` with a package not too particular about respecting initial file ownership and `rwx` mode. -- 1) to create a new user, keep it simple: first `sudo adduser my-user` then `sudo gpasswd -a my-user sudo`. Start again from scratch by deleting yr user if necessary. -- 2) to include a new entry with a `NOPASSWD` tag in `sudoers` or in a file in `/etc/sudoers.d/`, make the colon sticks to the tag. E.g. `NOPASSWD:`. I've not seen it before with interspersed space.

Comment: @Cbhihe: thanks for respecting my question; the problem is 100% about the file ownership. Your reply is usefull, please create an answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sometimes running a process from root's `crontab` may cause issues with initial file ownership and `rwx` mode; those may not be correctly preserved.

In any case:

1) to create a new user, keep it simple:

```
 $ sudo deluser my-user  # if "my-user" is a regular user
 $ adduser my-user
 $ sudo gpasswd -a my-user sudo
```

2) to include a new entry with a `NOPASSWD` tag in sudoers or in a file (e.g. `/etc/sudoers.d/60_my-user_rules`), make the colon stick to the tag, i.e. *`NOPASSWD:`*
I've not seen it before with interspersed space and yr rule becomes:

```
 my-user my-host = NOPASSWD: /full/path/to/cmd [parameter1 [| parameter2 [| ...]]]
```

Adding `(ALL)` before the `NOPASSWD:` is optional as the rule defaults to `(ALL:ALL)` anyway. You may however want to not only run your cmd/script with root privilege but also run it as either a given user (`spec-user`) or as a member of a given group (`spec-group`) or both. In that case, the rule becomes:

```
 my-user my-host = ([spec-user][:spec-group]) NOPASSWD: /full/path/to/cmd [parameter1 [| parameter2 [| ...]]]
```

This will actually restrict yr passwordless sudo disposition to one user, one host and one command. You can harden this rule by specifying the optional parameter(s) to that command. In that case the rule will apply only for that/those exact parameter(s).
For scripts, you could further harden this rule by ensuring that the rule applies only if the script was *not modified in any way*. This is a way to avoid script-hijacking. This is done through cmd-aliasing and specifying SHA-sums in `/etc/sudoers.d/60_my-user_rules`.

HTH. Please report if you experience issues with that answer.