# How can I use cron to restart apache in some conditions

Tags: apache2, cron

This is the first time I'm using cron. I want to restart the apacher in my server if the amount of available memory goes less than 500 mb. To do so I wrote the following script:

**restart_if_memory_full.sh (in  /var/www/myapp/)**

```
#!/bin/bash

mem=$(free -m | awk '/Mem:/{print $4}')
(( mem <= 500 )) && (sudo service apache2 restart)
```

Then I did it executable by running (`sudo chmod +x restart_if_memory_full.sh`) and added the following line to the cron by (`sudo crontab -e`) (Note I did not use .sh extension as recommended)

```
* * * * * /var/www/myapp/restart_if_memory_full
```

Now, I check the output by (`grep CRON /var/log/syslog`) and see this:

```
Nov 11 11:13:01 mardy2 CRON[31963]: (root) CMD (/var/www/myapp/restart_if_memory_full)
Nov 11 11:13:01 mardy2 CRON[31962]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)
```

However, when I check the memory usage by htop, it doesn't decrease and therefore I realized apache server was not restarted. So, how can I make this script runnable ?

Comment: The script IS running. Maybe it just doesn't work as you expect. It is a very bad idea to use `sudo` in cronjobs - think: how do I enter password to sudo ?

Comment: what @SorenA said with [link to explanation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/173924/how-to-run-a-cron-job-using-the-sudo-command)

Comment: There is no use in using `sudo` without specifying a user in a script if root runs it in the first place (as it is `root`'s crontab).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than doing a check every minute, I'd suggest running an endless script checking for your memory threshold and make it a `systemd`-service:

```
#!/bin/bash
#memory_check.sh
while [[ "free -m | awk '/Mem:/{print $4}'" -lt  500 ]] ; do
  sleep 5
done
```

---

```
#service called e.g. mem_check.service
[Unit]
Description=continuously monitors memory
After=apache2

[Service]
ExecStart=/path/to/memory_check.sh
Restart=on-failure
#let's give apache some time:
RestartSec=10s
```

---

Then add a restart dependeny to your `apache2.service` in  the `[Unit]` section with:

```
PartOf=mem_check.service
```

The `PartOf=` dependency forwards the restart of `mem_check` to `apache2`.

> PartOf=
>
> Configures dependencies similar to Requires=, but limited to stopping and restarting of units. When systemd stops or restarts the units listed here, the action is propagated to this unit. Note that this is a one-way dependency — changes to this unit do not affect the listed units.
>
> When PartOf=b.service is used on a.service, this dependency will show as ConsistsOf=a.service in property listing of b.service. ConsistsOf= dependency cannot be specified directly.

(from https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html)

Comment: Wow! I did not know any of these. Thanks for that.

Comment: You know how to activate `systemd`-services then? And where to place them? A quick [introduction](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/systemd-essentials-working-with-services-units-and-the-journal).