# Need Help in Creating Diskspace Script

Tags: scripts

I need help in creating a **script** that will run **once a day** in afternoon and collect the information of each partition(**Disk Space , Total and Used**)  and send it to my email.

Please help im very very new in this scripting thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provided you have an MTA configured on that machine to accept and relay mail for you (on a server that *should* be the case) try this:

```
$ df -h | mail -s "Filesystem usage report for `hostname`" myemail@domain.tld
```

(MTA = Postfix, Exim, etc.)

[image: Example emailed report]

If that fits your needs, add it to your *crontab* to run every day:

```
$ crontab -e
```

An editor will open. Add a line like this:

```
@daily df -h | mail -s ...
```

Save and close.

This will make it run with the other daily tasks. If you need a report on a specific time of the day or error logging to a specific address, please read about the cron syntax (a lot of this is on the Internet - [here](http://www.adminschoice.com/crontab-quick-reference)'s one random website). For example:

```
MAILTO=myerroraddress@domain.tld
# at 5 a.m every day:
0 5 * * * mycommand
```

In case you can't send out mail on that machine directly, read [this](http://garbers.co.za/2010/12/05/sending-mail-through-a-remote-smtp-server-in-linux/) or the answer by @hakermania on how to do that (many more ways exist).

Comment: I have not installed any mail server on my TEST PC. Can u please provide any good resource that can be used to install Posfix or Exim. I have searched for Posfix installation. most of them are very confusing . Which one should I install Postfix, Exim or Sendmail. Thanks

Comment: @UmairMustafa If it's just a PC and you're unfamiliar with MTA configurations I recommend you to use a script that uses authentication for a remote SMTP server instead. A lot depends on your situation - like whether you have a mail relay server in your network already.

Comment: Situation is this that I will first try it on my Test PC then later I will assign the same Script to each server in company running on linux. So tell me do I have to install Postfix first . If yes then I would really appreciate if u provide some assistance.

Comment: @UmairMustafa Configuring your mail gateway and relays is a completely differrent question. Try asking that kind of question on serverfault.com.

Answer (score 4):

In order to make the script running you will need to setup a cron job with it: [How do I setup a cronjob ?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2368/how-do-i-setup-cron-job)

Now, inside your script, you will need to do something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
#script that simply saves the output of df -h to an output file
#which is sent as an attachment to an e-mail

#a) save the output of the command:
temp_file=$(mktemp)

df -h > $temp_file 2> /dev/null

/root/email.py recipient@gmail.com "Title here" "Body here. The current date and time is $(date)" "$temp_file"

sleep 3
rm -rf $temp_file
```

As you can see, I'm calling a python script from within your root path (not readable but nobody else but root himself) which takes the following arguments:

"recipient-email" "title-of-email" "body-of-email" "attachment"

This python script is this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os, re
import sys
import smtplib

from email import encoders
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
from email.MIMEText import MIMEText


SMTP_SERVER = 'smtp.gmail.com'
SMTP_PORT = 587


sender = 'youremailhere@gmail.com'
password = "yourpasswordhere"
recipient = sys.argv[1]
subject = ''
message = sys.argv[3]

def main():
    msg = MIMEMultipart()
    msg['Subject'] = sys.argv[2]
    msg['To'] = recipient
    msg['From'] = sender

    part = MIMEText('text', "plain")
    part.set_payload(message)
    msg.attach(part)

    session = smtplib.SMTP(SMTP_SERVER, SMTP_PORT)

    session.ehlo()
    session.starttls()
    session.ehlo

    session.login(sender, password)

    fp = open(sys.argv[4], 'rb')
    msgq = MIMEBase('audio', 'audio')
    msgq.set_payload(fp.read())
    fp.close()
    # Encode the payload using Base64
    filename=sys.argv[4]
    msgq.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment', filename=filename)
    msg.attach(msgq)
    # Now send or store the message
    qwertyuiop = msg.as_string()



    session.sendmail(sender, recipient, qwertyuiop)

    session.quit()
    os.system('notify-send "Your disk space related email has been sent."')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Of course you will need to provide it with your **gmail** email and password at the top of the script (`sender` and `password` variables). If you install the `libnotify-bin` package, then, if the email was successfully sent, you will be notified with a desktop notification.

So, summing up, you will need to setup a cron job with the above **bash** script. This **bash** script will save the output of `df -h` inside a temporary file, which will be sent via a **python** script to a recipient email of your choice (as far as I remember, the sender email **must** be gmail).

PS: The above solution will show the free and total disk space only of your mounted filesystems. If this is a problem please inform me so as to extend my answer about how to automatically mount all the available filesystems and then run `df -h`.

Comment: I recommend using the [``sendemail``](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/sendemail) package for sending mails to remote SMTP servers directly instead.

Comment: @gertvdijk please feel free to edit the answer and include yours as well, pointing out why `sendemail` may be a better option. Or add it as an answer!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this script to check the disk usage

```
#!/bin/bash

limit=85
email=you@domain.com
host=`hostname`
out=`df -k | grep "^/dev" | awk '{ if($5 > $limit) print "\nDisk space is critial on " $1,$5,$6 "\n"}'`
usr/bin/mail -s "Disk Space Alert on $host: $out" $email
```

Use `cron` to make the script run automatically. Check this online [cron generator](http://cron.nmonitoring.com/cron-generator.html) for helping you in setting it up.