# "load" a URL in terminal

Tags: command-line, url

I put "load" in quotes because I'm not trying to open up a website via terminal. I have a PHP script on a web server that logs to a text file when it has been loaded. I'd like to set up a cron on a battery powered linux system to load the URL for this PHP script once per minute. I'd like to do this so that it runs until the battery dies and I can see how long it ran for by viewing the txt file on my server.

I'm trying to find out if there is something like a "ping" command for a specific URL, not just a server or IP. Hopefully that makes sense. =)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I set up a Cron job?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/2368/how-do-i-set-up-a-cron-job)

Comment: @papukaija That question doesn't answer how to access the URL.

Comment: Perhaps curl or wget?

Answer (score 4):

In your battery powered device run `crontab -e` then add this line at the end:

```
* * * * * wget -q -O- http://www.example.com/full/URL/path.php > /dev/null
```

It will run every minute and the HTML code returned by your PHP script (if any) will be simply discarded.

Comment: wget! I don't know how I forgot about that... Thanks for even providing the whole crontab line needed. It's more than I was even asking for! =)