# How do I set up PHP and MySQL cronjobs on Ubuntu 12.04 (Precise Pangolin) server?

Tags: 12.04, command-line, mysql, php, cron

I just made a [LAMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LAMP_%28software_bundle%29) install and got [SFTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SFTP) working. My question now is: How do I set up cronjobs on Ubuntu server?

I need to make some cronjobs for my PHP/MySQL application. I look for un-activated users in my MySQL table, delete them, etc.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I set up a Cron job?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/2368/how-do-i-set-up-a-cron-job)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way that keeps all the code together is to create a web script (authenticated by some "secret", so random people can't call it for you) and call it from cron using:

```
wget -O - http://<yoursite>/cron.php?secret=<mybigsecret>
```

Then you need to add a cron entry (either using crontab -e), or just placing a file into:

```
/etc/cron.d/
```

with following contents:

```
0 3 * * * nobody wget -O - http://yoursite/cron.php?secret=<mybigsecret>
```

This will call the script every day at 03:00, for more information on crontab files syntax please consult crontab(5) man page (e.g. run "man 5 crontab").