# Send mail from the terminal

Tags: 12.04, postfix

I need to send continuous mails, say one every minute, for testing purposes from a server running postfix.
With the `mail` command I can manually do it, although there is no specific option to trigger it to auto send mails.

Comment: You need to set up a cron job:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/2368/how-do-i-set-up-a-cron-job

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best way to do this is via a cron job. Type `crontab -e` in a terminal (you have to be root).

And add a line with the following content:

```
* * * * * /bin/echo "content" | /usr/bin/mail -s "subject" email@provider.tld
```

And save the file. It will send every minute a mail. After that restart the cron daemon:

```
service cron restart
```

See [cron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) for how to set other time scheduling.

Comment: One does **NOT** have to be `root` to use `cron`! Read `man crontab` especially about `/etc/cron.allow`