# Execute command on time Shell Script

Tags: scripts, command-line

I want to say I am a complete newbie but I want a shell script that will execute a command on a specific time for example on 6:45 am

How is this done, a full example would be very useful! Thank you!

Comment: You may have what you want here at [how-do-i-set-up-a-cron-job](http://askubuntu.com/questions/2368/how-do-i-set-up-a-cron-job/)

Answer (score 2):

You want to use `cron`.

You create schedules within your `crontab` (`crontab -e`). The syntax of how to do that can be seen [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron#Predefined_scheduling_definitions).

If you wanted to clear `/tmp/` at 6:45 AM every day you'd have something like the following in your `crontab`:

`45 6 * * * /bin/rm -rf /tmp/*`