# Random warnings at startup

Tags: startup, thunderbird

When I reboot the system, *sometimes* I get the warning messages saying `System problem detected.` When this happens, except this apport message, entire screen goes blank and after some time, session starts as usual.

Weird part is that this happens randomly and not during every reboot. Below is `/etc/rc.local`

```
#!/bin/sh -e
#
# rc.local
#
# This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel.
# Make sure that the script will "exit 0" on success or any other
# value on error.
#
# In order to enable or disable this script just change the execution
# bits.
#
# By default this script does nothing.
sleep 10
rfkill block bluetooth
sudo mount /dev/sda2 /media/nitish
thunderbird&
exit 0
```

thunderbird when executed through terminal gives these errors

```
(process:2462): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_slice_set_config: assertion 'sys_page_size == 0'   failed

(thunderbird:2462): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: Attempt to add property GnomeProgram::sm-connect after class was initialised

(thunderbird:2462): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: Attempt to add property GnomeProgram::show-crash-dialog after class was initialised

(thunderbird:2462): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: Attempt to add property GnomeProgram::display after class was initialised

(thunderbird:2462): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: Attempt to add property GnomeProgram::default-icon after class was initialised
[calBackendLoader] Using libical backend at /usr/lib/thunderbird/extensions/{e2fda1a4-762b-4020-b5ad-a41df1933103}/components/libical.manifest
```

and then starts normally.

Does this cause any problem? Even then, why does this problem not occur every time I reboot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have to say that you are doing things the wrong way:

1. `thunderbird&`:

   Those warnings are not random. What you are doing here is executing Thunderbird as root... **you shouldn't!** If you need to start a program when your system boots up, specially if they use GUI's, you should add them to the [startup application list instead](https://askubuntu.com/q/48321/169736). Runing any application connected to the internet is extremally dangerous and Thunderbird could have vulnerabilities that would left an attacker several vectors of attack. **Remove that line!**
2. `sudo mount /dev/sda2 /media/nitish`:

   Why not to use the `/etc/fstab` file? You only need to [add a line in the fstab](https://askubuntu.com/q/34731/169736) file and it will get [mounted at boot](https://askubuntu.com/a/271527/169736), without complications.
3. `rfkill block bluetooth`:

   I believe that adding the bluetooth modules to the modules blacklist is more preferable, and you can add it again easily.

   ```
   sudo sh -c "echo 'blacklist bluetooth' >> /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-bluetooth.conf"
   ```

   Of course, the module name can be anything. Check `lsmod` to be sure.