# Problem with setting wallpaper using gsettings

Tags: gnome, desktop-background, gsettings

I used `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri 'file://PathToImage'` to set an image as a wallpaper as suggested in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/69500/149979). This does not do the job properly. For today's bing image, [script here](https://askubuntu.com/a/385836/149979) changes my background like this

[image: Image of my desktop]

This happens at random and sometimes it sets the wallpaper properly. Using GUI, setting the image as wallpaper by right-clicking on it works properly every time. Any possible causes of this problem?

Edit1: The download is perfectly fine. As I have mentioned, I can set the photo as wallpaper by right clicking the photo and chosing 'set as wallpaper' from the menu.

Comment: I don't know for sure, but I suspect that the download is failing (only downloading a partial file) or the background is being displayed before the download is complete - do you have any way of confirming that the download is complete?

Comment: Please see the edit in question.

Comment: Try `rm /home/$USER/.cache/wallpaper/*` before executing script. Let me know if it work.

Comment: It worked for today, but since I am facing this issue randomly, I cannot guarantee. Can you please explain why the cache is causing a problem?

Comment: How today ....?

Comment: Yeah. It's perfect

Answer (score 5):

You mentioned

> The download is perfectly fine. As I have mentioned, I can set the photo as wallpaper by right clicking the photo and chosing 'set as wallpaper' from the menu.

As you can manually set the wallpaper the problem may be on the cache, which is generated before the downloader completely write the data on the file. So regenerating the cache in this kind of case is necessary.

So delete wallpaper cache `rm /home/$USER/.cache/wallpaper/*` .
Add this code to end of the script after some `sleep`.

## Let's do a test

1. Find and open the image cache of current wallpaper from `/home/$USER/.cache/wallpaper/`
2. Edit the image ( such as rotate clockwise. You can do it with the default imageg viwer (GNOME image viewer) using Ctrl+R (Or from edit -> rotate))
3. Logout and login ubuntu (or restart)

That's it now you can see the changes on the desktop wallpaper (If you rotated the image, then the wallpaper will also get rotated)

Comment: This command: `rm /home/$USER/.cache/wallpaper/*` doesn't have nothing to do with the new wallpaper; it only removes the wallpaper used before to launch the script. So, it doesn't help with nothing.

Comment: You are correct. fixing

Comment: Adding that command to the end of the script it also doesn't help. Following your test, after re-login, the desktop will remain without any wallpaper.

Comment: You may need to reboot. It worked for me

Comment: Yes, this is working for me!!

Comment: Forgive me for hijacking your answer, but I have [a similar question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/590607/why-do-i-only-get-half-a-desktop-wallpaper) that you might be able to shed some light on?

Answer (score 2):

The following command is correct and should work in any circumstance:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri 'file://PathToImage'
```

So, I assume that the main reason why this thing is happen is because, as @d3vid noted in his [comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/393335/problem-with-setting-wallpaper-using-gsettings#comment514298_393335): *the download is failing (only downloading a partial file) or the background is being displayed before the download is complete*.

To solve your problem be sure that you have a better internet connection when you run [the script](https://askubuntu.com/a/385836/149979) from your question or try to use [`curl`](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/curl/) instead of `wget` as in the script from my answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/400984/147044).

Comment: I don't think the problem is with the download, because, the photo is perfectly fine.

Comment: @nitish If the photo is perfectly fine, then run again `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri 'file://PathToImage'`. I'm sure that this time it will looks good on your desktop. The problem is that when you run that script, `gsettings` will probably start before `wget` to finish completely. And for this I suggested you to use `curl` instead of `wget`. Or add a line like `sleep 5` after `wget` line which will make the script to wait 5 seconds before to run `gsettings`.

Comment: ..or combine `wget` and `gsettings` commands with `&&` operator in the [script](http://askubuntu.com/questions/379377/bing-picture-of-the-day-as-desktop-wallpaper/385836#385836) like this: `wget [wget_command_parameters] && gsettings [gsettings_command_parameters]`

Comment: @RaduRădeanu, I tried that before. I put `sleep 5` after `wget`.In fact, the image that I put on this question is produced by the script even with `sleep 5`

Comment: @nitish Then your internet connection is even worse; try with more: `sleep 20`, `sleep 30`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe in the script, you should first download the new picture in a temporary file like:

```
wget --no-proxy --output-document=dwallpaper.temp (...)
```

And only after the `wget` command is done, do:

```
cp dwallpaper.temp dwallpaper
```

This way, `gsettings` is always pointing to a file 100% downloaded which may fix the issue you observed.