# Why do I only get half a desktop wallpaper?

Tags: desktop-background, wget, gsettings

I've created a neat little script that downloads a JPG using `wget`and then sets it as the Unity desktop background with

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri file:///home/myname/wallpaper.jpg
```

After running the script, the **desktop wallpaper is incomplete** but when I open the downloaded image, it is fine! When I manually run the `gsettings` command, the same thing happens - so I don't think the problem could be that `gsettings` starts before the image is downloaded completely.

What is causing this odd problem, and how can I fix it?

- **Exhibit A:** [my neat little script](https://github.com/torbengb/bash/blob/master/daylight-wallpaper-install.sh).
- **Exhibit B:** My desktop with an incomplete background image:
  [image].
- **Exhibit C:** [original image url](http://www.opentopia.com/images/data/sunlight/world_sunlight_map_rectangular.jpg). The trick is that this URL is static but **the actual image file is continually refreshed** with a different image file. That's why I made my script.
- **Exhibit D:** When the desktop is broken, manually setting the wallpaper through the Settings GUI (or desktop right-click) fixes it ... until the cron'ed script runs again.
- **Exhibit E:** When the desktop is broken, manually running `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri file:///home/myname/wallpaper.jpg`
   doesn't fix it.
- **Exhibit F:** When the desktop is broken, manually running `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-options zoom` doesn't fix it. Nothing seems to happen.
- **Exhibit G:** When the desktop is broken, the cached wallpaper is also broken. I came across [this very similar topic](https://askubuntu.com/a/402729/5786). Adding `rm` of the cached file before the `gsettings` command doesn't solve my problem though; the new cached image is broken too. It almost seems like that `gsettings` command is broken?

Comment: Does th wallpaper load correctly when you change to it via GUI (my guess is no)?

Comment: Yes that works too!

Comment: To get it clear, if you run (only) `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri file:///home/myname/wallpaper.jpg` on the *downloaded* file, it appears only half?

Comment: Yes, correct @JacobVlijm. (I'm on 14.10).

Comment: An irrational and wild guess, but what if you run (with half of the world on your screen): `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-options zoom` (in an attempt to force refresh)

Comment: Nope,  no luck. Nothings seems to happen.

Comment: Just as information, it shows perfectly on my system with the command...

Comment: Just that command, or the entire script? Would you mind trying the script?

Comment: Runs absolutely perfectly! Do you have a poor graphics card/driver?

Comment: I also get partial image and noticed that the image is drawn dynamically as if the file is downloading (but it has downloaded already). Perhaps, if you put a wait time after download and before the gsetting, then you may get the full image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your purpose is to display the current earth view, you might make use of xplanet, which gets a more frequently updated image.

Install xplanet with -

`sudo apt-get install xplanet`

Then, in your script replace the image source with the xplanet output as below.

`xplanet -body earth -num_times 1 -projection mercator -output $wallpaper_name -geometry 1366x768`
(replace geometry parameter value with your screen size).

Now, you will get a more frequently updated image that won't be sliced.

Comment: There's a program that generates these and can be run on the local computer? How cool is that! I'll never _not_ be surprised by the versatility of Linux :D

Comment: Yes, xplanet can run a continuous image update, however your script will allow a more judicious use of personal computer resource. A cron with 15 minute update interval is quite appropriate for personal use :)

Comment: Your answer doesn't explain the cause of my current problem but provides a fine alternative solution that I want to implement. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks to you too. I changed my desktop/wallpaper to this interesting journey through the day.

Comment: Now having toyed with `xplanet` I can't decide whether to use it or not. It does produce a very nice image but the nighttime area seems wrong - too bright and missing city lights. For that, the Opentopia images win. Hmm...