# Dynamic info on wallpaper on Ubuntu just like Mac OSX?

Tags: desktop-background, automation

As you can see in this picture, the wallpaper has it's clock change. This (from [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/Firewatch/comments/445yim/my_firewatch_mac_custom_wallpaper/), read the top comment) is actually real since there was a download link for this.

So in short, 2 questions

- Will I be able to stick a giant clock after the clouds like this? Or at least make the clock show after the image alpha layer?
- Will Ubuntu be able to change the wallpaper depending on the weather? (like [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/Firewatch/comments/446g00/firewatch_custom_20_wallpapers_different_times_of/) set of wallpaper that has a comment saying that he/she can use `IFTTT` which I'm not quite sure)

[image: The picture]

Comment: I don't think Ubuntu supports "live" wallpapers. You could script something, based on http://askubuntu.com/questions/664411/automatically-change-ubuntu-wallpaper-at-a-certain-hour, http://askubuntu.com/questions/379377/bing-picture-of-the-day-as-desktop-wallpaper

Comment: @JacobVlijm Ah. So you only need to somehow edit the text file each minute according to the time? But how?

Comment: Anyway according to @muru 's answer then the package `variety` isn't available for 15.10 :(

Comment: @JacobVlijm But any better way? Like a script used to display clock on a screen and an overlay for the desktop? Like the desktop has the clock, and then a wallpaper overlay?

Comment: @JacobVlijm You can also use wallpaper clocks - http://www.vladstudio.com/wallpaperclocks/

Comment: @JacobVlijm  Hold. Are there any way that helps me to change wallpaper based on weather?

Comment: @JacobVlijm Ways? Maybe using the OpenWeatherMap? `weatherpaper` has Yahoo Weather which is broken now (no more weather IDs) and the importing part was just dead.

Comment: @dattutbrus you might want to edit your question a bit. It is hard to answer in a concrete way as it is. A clock on the wallpaper is very well doable (have it ready), posting it on the question as it is seems weird. What is concrete the answer you are expecting?

Comment: @JacobVlijm How to make the wallpaper change according to weather? (That's for now.)

Comment: @Parto: Your suggestions sounds very promising. Can you please convert your comment to an answer and elaborate a little? Ping me for an up-vote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Info on desktop

You can use [`conky`](https://github.com/brndnmtthws/conky).

#### Installation

Just install the [`conky-all`](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/conky-all) package.

#### Configuration

Create a file named `.conkyrc` (note the dot) in `~/`. The format for `.conkyrc`s is documented [here](http://conky.sourceforge.net/docs.html)

You can also get good-looking "ready-made" `conkyrc`s here: [DeviantArt](http://www.deviantart.com/browse/all/?section=&global=1&q=conky)

## Change wallpaper based on weather and time

So, apparently WeatherPaper does not work. So, I made my own: https://github.com/bharadwaj-raju/WeatherDesk

Comment: Weather didn't work. Running `install.sh` makes a shortcut however running the shortcut failed. When I import themes it crashed.

Comment: @dattutbrus Can you post the error?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/GK6UKU2S Here it is

Comment: @dattutbrus I too love those wallpapers so I made my own wallpaper changer - https://github.com/bharadwaj-raju/WeatherDesk

Comment: Nice application written in Python script! Will try asap. Thanks.

Comment: @dattutbrus Did it work?

Comment: After many weeks of editing the cloudy pictures for the app, I've finally made it. However, 2 things. One, can I have your day and night cloudy pictures? And two, I would love to use Open Weather than Yahoo Weather because they are open...

Comment: @dattutbrus Great to know! For the cloud pictures - I just use the normal ones :). As for OpenWeatherMap, it was the service I first considered for the script, though the fact that it needed a whole lot of API key complexity, I went with Yahoo. But now that Yahoo has been bought and the future is uncertain, I may switch to OpenWeatherMap.

Comment: @dattutbrus the reason I'm considering OpenWeatherMap now is that since this is an open source project, I don't need all that API key thing.

Comment: Also I really like the fact that you don't need to type the city name which was too annoying in previous weather apps. Also, I can't seem to find a cloudy picture.

Comment: 2018 update: There's now Komorebi in Vala: https://github.com/cheesecakeufo/komorebi

Answer (score 2):

### Using Wallpaper Clocks in Ubuntu

#### #1: Install Wallch

First we need to install an application that supports wallpaper clocks in Ubuntu. [Slidewall](https://launchpad.net/slidewall) - the application recommended by vladstudio doesn't work with Ubuntu 14.04; instead we are going to install [Wallch (Wallpaper Changer)](https://sourceforge.net/projects/wall-changer/).

1. [Download](https://sourceforge.net/projects/wall-changer/files/4.0/) Wallch 32bit or 64 bit depending on your system architecture.
2. Install it via the software Center or via command line
   `sudo dpkg -i /home/parto/Desktop/wallch_4.12-1trusty_i386.deb`
3. Launch Wallch either via the dash or in terminal by typing the command: `wallch`

#### #2: Get your desktop display resolution

We need to know the resolution of our display so as to know which wallpaper size to download.

1. Launch system settings and select `Display`
2. Note your screen resolution somewhere. Mine is 1366x768.

[image]

#### #3: Download Wallpaper Clocks

To download Wallpaper Clocks:

1. Go to [Vlad Studio](http://www.vladstudio.com/wallpaperclocks/browse.php) and click on a wallpaper clock of your choice.
2. Let us choose [Airlines 2](http://www.vladstudio.com/wallpaperclock/?airlines2)

[image]

3. Download the **.wcz** file using the resolution size of your display as noted above. Mine was 1366x768.

[image]

4. Save it in your computer.

#### #4: Add Wallpaper Clocks to Wallch

To add the wallpaper Clock to Wallch:

1. Launch wallch.
2. Select the `Wallpaper Clocks` tab and click the `Install` button.

[image]

2. Browse to your `.wcz` file and select it. Then click on the `Activate Wallpaper Clock` button. 
   **Do not extract it, just open it as it is.**

[image]

3. It will be set automatically as your desktop background, with the correct time and date.

Here's my desktop.

[image]

Comment: @DavidFoerster Done.

Comment: This is nice but unfortunately it has to use a preset wallpaper. Are there any way to make one?