# Command to delete old Minecraft backups

Tags: minecraft

I need to delete backups older than *x* days and I'd like it to be automatic to a point. Is there a way to clear backups on my Minecraft server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will use FIND command to do this, you will have to create a bash script and a CRON job.

Please read the man for FIND.

```
find /u1/database/prod/arch -type f -mtime +3 -exec rm {} \;
```

This command finds all the files under /u1/database/prod/arch and it's subfolders, that are "regular files" (-type f) not directories, device files or something like that, and that have been modified at least 3 days ago (-mtime +3) and then executes "rm " for those files.

Comment: P.S. This is how you create a Cron Job, follow link. 

http://askubuntu.com/questions/2368/how-do-i-set-up-a-cron-job

Comment: Thanks Chris ive been working hard on learning linux but so far ive had fun :)