# How to Schedule a Shell Script

Tags: 12.04, command-line, schedule

i wanted to schedule shell scripts in my ubuntu 12.04. i know "at". but i wanted some thing that would schedule my shell script exactly at 12:00 AM or exactly on the first day of a month repeatedly!

Comment: Check http://askubuntu.com/questions/2368/how-do-i-set-up-a-cron-job

Answer (score 1):

That would be `cron`.  See `man crontab` and run `crontab -e` to edit your cron jobs.