# Exit terminal after scheduled command

Tags: command-line

I am trying to run Unison to sync my files locally. I want that to occur periodically, without the need of any interaction. For that reason I run gnome-schedule with the following command:

```
unison Folder -silent -ui text
```

Everything works fine, just the terminal stays open and prompts for ENTER. I want to exit the terminal automatically after finishing the syncronization. How could I do this?

Thanks and greetings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the `exit` builtin function so that terminal may close automatically.Just add `exit` at the end of the command as

```
unison Folder -silent -ui text;exit
```

This will exit the terminal after command executes.

Comment: Thanks, worked great. I had tried this command before, but missed the ";". Is there a command to avoid that the terminal window pops up, when the command is executed?

Comment: You need to set up a cron job.read http://askubuntu.com/q/2368/184942. actually you are doing the same but with a GUI frontend.I think CLI method does not pop up a terminal.