# write a bash which open firefox on every ten minute

Tags: command-line, bash, time, execute-command

Is it possible to write an script which do a specific command every ten minute?
I do not know if this is a loop?  For example Every ten minute delete a file name foo on the home directory? or every ten minute open firefox. 
**Update: please how to do that with out CRON I need bash script**

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I set up a Cron job?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/2368/how-do-i-set-up-a-cron-job)

Comment: @Jobin thanks for link.For do every ten minute on the bash, Am I should learn Cron?Is there any function on the bash which do that? for every ten minute?

Comment: @alex - depends on what kind of loop you like most. Loop with while or if blabla not to recommend. Type with unix-system at good google search words: bash switch case script

Comment: @dschinn1001 yes For example I want to open firefox every ten minute.Just that I do not have knowledge about cron, but I think it will some thing on the bash script, which opens firefox or delete a file every ten minute

Comment: http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/07/bash-case-statement/

Comment: good - you can read and eat salad - ;)

Comment: patience please - deliver script today ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#!/bin/sh
while :
do
  firefox
  sleep 600
done
```

Comment: little warning - while could be bad, cause it is only allowed on local machines ...