# Can I automate filesystem cleanup?

Tags: automation, cleanup

I have a multi-user system and recently started receiving messages saying

```
low disk space in filesystem /root
```

and the same for `/boot`.

`/boot` was at 100% capacity, so I ran:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

I want to automate this so I don't have to do it manually. Thanks from a first-timer!

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/questions/2368/how-do-i-set-up-a-cron-job

Comment: Here is another one with examples... http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/06/15-practical-crontab-examples/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just set up a cron job to run say, every 2 hours like this....

```
sudo crontab -e
```

When the editor starts, add this to the end

```
0 */2 * * *  apt-get autoremove
```

If you are using the default editor (nano) hit `Control O` (the letter) and `Enter` to save and then `Control X` to exit.

Comment: Thanks! And to just to be clear, these will run as a root command, not just for one user?

Comment: @mrtommy Since we are editing root's crontab (note the `sudo`), this will run as the root user.