# How to get a notification when computer is not charging?

Tags: power-management, notification

My laptop battery sucks, and lasts up to 5minutes without charging. Sometimes the charger falls out without me knowing, making the computer shut off unexpectedly.

Is there a way to get a notification the moment my charger falls out? not when battery needs to be charged like Ubuntu is used to do(Because that doesn't work for my laptop, and I've given up that idea)

Comment: [check this answer by @JacobVlijm](http://askubuntu.com/a/519045/283843). this answer alert you if battery charge is below 40%. You can change the source to 10% or below.

Comment: Thanks, but not exactly what I'm looking for, there's something wrong with my battery I think, and the percentage showing is incorrect, and it's empty with 95% or something. I'm looking to get a notification for not charging my laptop

Comment: Just to note that in KDE you could have set it all from GUI only as a standard behavior.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simple linear command:

```bsh
[[ $(acpi -b | grep -o "Discharging") ]] && notify-send "Alert" "Battery is not charging.\n Please plug your AC adapter!"
```

---

From `man acpi` we have:

```bsh
NAME
       acpi - Shows battery status and other ACPI information    
SYNOPSIS
       acpi [options]    
DESCRIPTION
       acpi Shows information from the /proc or the /sys filesystem, such as battery status or thermal information.    
OPTIONS
       -b | --battery
                 show battery information
```

---

If you run `acpi -b` and you battery is charging mode, you will get this result of that:

```bsh
Battery 0: Charging, 88%, 00:38:17 until charged
```

And if your battery isn't charging then the result would be like this:

```bsh
Battery 0: Discharging, 87%, 03:46:06 remaining
```

Then We are looking "Discharging" in the result with this command:

```bsh
acpi -b | grep -o "Discharging"
```

If battery was not in charging the result will **"Discharging"**.

And finally we send an alert to notification if we got "**Discharging**" from above command:

```bsh
[[ $(acpi -b | grep -o "Discharging") ]] && notify-send "Alert" "Battery is not charging.\n Please plug your AC adapter!"
```

Note: `[[ Something ]]` always true and `[[ ! Something ]]` always false.

Now it's easiest way that we run it in the background, inside a while loop. Then I put the command into a while loop and I check the battery status between X interval of time. Like this:

```bsh
while true
 do
    # Our command
    sleep [number of seconds] # check the status every [number of seconds] seconds
 done
```

And if you want to run the script on startup and every 5 minutes, so the construction would be:

- Save the script(I named it `ChkCharge.sh` in my home directory)
- Add a line in `/etc/rc.local` to call your script (your `ChkCharge.sh`) + "&" to make it exit. like `bash /home/USERNAME/ChkCharge.sh &`.

---

**Final Script**

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
while true
do
    [[ $(acpi -b | grep -o "Discharging") ]] && notify-send "Alert" "Battery is not charging.\n Please plug your AC adapter!"
    sleep 300 # 300 seconds or 5 minutes
done
```

Finish. Reboot and see the magic ;)

Comment: It's so great to see different ways to achieve the same goal :)

Comment: The script works great, but the startup thingy doesn't work for me :/ http://khp.randompoop.net/uploads/Screenshot%20from%202014-10-04%2020:45:47.png does that look right?

Comment: @Jeggy run directly the script `sh /home/jeggy/.startup/ChkCharge.sh` and see if runs without any errors.

Comment: /home/jeggy/.startup/ChkCharge.sh: 4: /home/jeggy/.startup/ChkCharge.sh: [[: not found

Comment: @Jeggy use `bash` instead of `sh` at the begging and run again

Comment: I changed the code to this: http://paste.ubuntu.com/8495663/
as it didn't say charging when it was charging with 100% and thanks bash did work instead of sh :D

Comment: tested, but the startup thingy still doesn't work :/ I changed it to 3seconds for testing purposes. **bash /home/jeggy/.startup/ChkCharge.sh** works

Comment: @Jeggy I have updated answer. yes may be your `/etc/rc.local` don't want to start. try this command to force start it `sudo /etc/rc.local start` and check if that runs the script. if worked then you have to open new question to solve your problem that your `rc.local` doesn't run your script at startup ;)

Comment: alright, thanks. That did work, so I'll just open a new question.  I have accepted your answer :)

Answer (score 4):

This looks pretty simple, I'm not a bash script expert, but maybe could be useful for you

```
# sh script.sh
```

The `script.sh` content:

```bsh
#! /bin/bash

power=$(cat /sys/class/power_supply/BAT1/status)

while true; do
  actual=$(cat /sys/class/power_supply/BAT1/status)

  if [ $actual != $power ]; then
     power=$actual
     notify-send $actual
  fi
done
```

Basically, I'm reading a file at `sysfs` that has information about your battery, there are more information in there that could be interesting. The file `status` contains a flag indicating if your device is actually **Charging** or **Discharging**. Hope that helps you.

Comment: You don't need to store last status `power=$(cat /sys/class/power_supply/BAT1/status)`. just compare `$temp !="Charging"`. You are good ;)

Comment: But this way I can get notifications when power supply is connected and when it's disconnected.

Comment: This line `actual=$(cat /sys/class/power_supply/BAT1/status)` checks if power supply is connected("Charging") or dis(Discharging), and the goal is "if battery not charging", then you need only check the `actual=$(cat /sys/class/power_supply/BAT1/status)` and compare it with "Charging", if they are not equal then we will know that, the battery is not charging. **both ways are correct**. and one more thing, replace  `$temp` to `$actual`

Comment: Also it could be a problem to hardcode it to look at `BAT1`... On my system for example the battery is located at `BAT0`. So I think the other answer using the `acpi` command might be more elegant/universal