# Changing screen Brightness with a script

Tags: 14.04, laptop, power-management, brightness, battery

As you may know, screen brightness drains battery, that's why it is considered a big problem for laptops (at least for me).

I can change the screen brightness but every time ubuntu boots up I will have to change it again.

Luckily, you can write a [script that does that for you.](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/04/save-screen-brightness-settings-in-ubuntu-14-04/) However, when the laptop is plugged in I *do* want the maximum brightness; which means I will have to do that by myself every time I plug in the laptop.

Is there a script that detect if the laptop is charging or not and sets the brightness level accordingly?

Comment: also see [How to get a notification when computer is not charging?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/532182/how-to-get-a-notification-when-computer-is-not-charging/532216#532216)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On my laptop I can check the contents of the file `/sys/class/power_supply/C1BC/online`: if the laptop is plugged in this file contains `1`, otherwise it contains `0`.

For example,

```sh
if [ "1" = "`cat /sys/class/power_supply/C1BC/online`" ]; then
  echo "Laptop is charging/plugged"
else
  echo "Laptop is discharging/unplugged"
fi
```

**Note.** As confirmed by the OP, the `C1BC` part is system dependent.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Mine was ACAD though.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

To [adjust brightness in xubuntu or ubuntu](http://namhuy.net/528/adjust-brightness-in-xubuntu.html)
Open a terminal window, and execute this command to edit /etc/rc.local:

```
sudo nano /etc/rc.local
```

Add this before the last line “exit 0″:

```
echo xx > /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness
```

Where number `xx` is the value of your screen brightness of your choice.

The maximum value for brightness can be found with:

```
cat /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/max_brightness
```