# How can I limit battery charging to 60% capacity?

Tags: 18.04, asus, battery, charging

I have an Asus ROG GL503 laptop, which came pre-installed with Asus Battery Health Charging software. This software gives me the option to limit my battery charging level to 60% to prolong the overall battery lifespan. Whenever I boot using Ubuntu(18.04), my battery keeps charging until it reaches 100%. Is there any method by which I can limit my battery charging up to a certain level?

Comment: Sorry but if it is a LI-ON that is the WORST advice EVER. LI-ON batteries have a limited amount of charges. Oh and you need kernel support for this. AFAIK only Thinkpads have that https://askubuntu.com/questions/34452/how-can-i-limit-battery-charging-to-80-capacity

Comment: You are better of taking out the battery when on the mains OR have it discharge to near 0 and then charge back to 100 once every so often,

Comment: @Rinzwind, not sure this is true for modern batteries without memory effects. Charging while near zero or near full causes more strain to the battery (high currents versus high potentials in these extreme zones), which decreases life time compared to where a battery is kept between 20 - 80%.

Comment: You can indeed prolong moderns Li-Ion batteries lifespan by keeping them at a lower charge. If you never ever use it disconnected, you should keep it at 40%. E.g. Uber driver cellphone always-on in travels. However for daily light usage, 60% is considered the 'sweet spot' for practicality, and 80% gives you more freedom. 100% is when the battery is at its peak 'stress' level, and thus wear faster. Charge-Discharge cycles also impact wear rates. Same for temperature, where higher usually = worse, except when you get close to freezing temps or below, where weird things happen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have written a short python script to make switching the thresholds easier on my ROG laptop. (ROG STRIX G731GU).

Please run the script as admin. (e.g. `sudo python3 scriptname.py`)

```
power_cfg = open("/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/charge_control_end_threshold", "r")
print("Current Charge Threshold:")

print(power_cfg.read())
power_cfg = open("/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/charge_control_end_threshold", "w")
change_opt = input("Change? y/n: ")

if(change_opt == "y"):
    ch_val = input("Enter New Value: ");
power_cfg.write(ch_val);
```

Please let me know if this works on your machine.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK there's no software triggered hardware switch to turn off power after reaching certain point in general purpose laptops or notebooks.

However, you may run a background script that can inform/**alert** you when you reach a desired battery level percentage.

Refer this link for knowing how to listen to Battery Levels:

[How to write a script to "listen" to battery status and alert me when it's above 60% or below 40%?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/518928/how-to-write-a-script-to-listen-to-battery-status-and-alert-me-when-its-above)

It still won't be automated though.

Answer (score 0):

**Bat a Github solution only for ASUS laptop**

You can use now  the utility bat that has the same behaviour as the original ASUS utility [link](https://www.asus.com/us/support/FAQ/1032726/):

Installing this precompiled binary I set a threshold to charge my laptop battery only at 60 % but anyway you can choose the thresold you prefer.

I 'm succesfully using Bat in my Asus vivobook pro 15 N580GD with ubuntu 20.04.

This is the GIT link:
https://github.com/leveson/bat

Precompiled binaries (Linux x86-64) are available from the GitHub releases page, the latest of which can be downloaded from  [here](https://github.com/leveson/bat/releases/download/0.6/bat).

In my case I've only downloaded the precompiled binary and copied this to the dir

```
sudo cp bat /usr/local/bin/
```

so then you ' ll be able to use it from your command line from any path in your system and set the battery threshold as  you prefer (see below in Commands)

**Requirements**

Linux kernel version later than 5.4 which is the earliest version to expose the battery charging threshold variable. Is required also systemd at least version 244, and Bash which are bundled with most Linux distribution.

**Commands**

Check current threshold

```
bat -t
```

set threshold to the value you prefer ( I suggest 60% )

```
sudo bat -t 60
```

makes modified  threshold persistant

```
sudo bat -p
```

makes current threshold valid only for current session

```
sudo bat -r
```

shows current level of charge

```
sudo bat -c
```

Shows current charging status

```
sudo bat -s
```

Answer (score 0):

I have an Asus TUF working fine with [TLP](https://linrunner.de/tlp/settings/introduction.html) (limited battery charge to 70%) and [TLPUI](https://github.com/d4nj1/TLPUI). Try this:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:linrunner/tlp
sudo apt install tlp tlp-rdw

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:linuxuprising/apps
sudo apt install tlpui
```

Then, use "tlpui" in your applications to setup this.