# Is there a known way to get the battery to stop charging at 60% with Ubuntu on a Lenovo g50-30?

Tags: power-management, lenovo, battery, tlp, battery-charging-threshold

I recently setup dual boot to Ubuntu on my Lenovo g50-30. One of the reasons for doing this was because I was getting annoyed that 'conversation mode' (using Lenovo Energy Manager) was being reset every time the power was removed on shutdown. Conservation mode remains on reboot, but if the laptop isn't continually connected to power, conservation mode is reset once I log back in to Windows.

I read some threads on setting a charging threshold on Ubuntu, so I thought it would be possible. However, now that I have dual booted the laptop, it doesn't seem so easy.

I have found these threads which are somewhat related: [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1056198/how-can-i-stop-charging-my-battery-at-60), and [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34452/how-can-i-limit-battery-charging-to-80-capacity?newreg=1f419ea7e1044934b6ce796cc2369049). I've tried some of the methods, but I run into errors, which I believe is expected because they seem to be specific methods for Asus machines or Lenovo Thinkpads.

Some people have had a 'problem' that their computers have been stuck in conservation mode after dual booting Ubuntu with Windows, but this 'problem' is what I want. I tried to set conservation mode on windows and log back into Ubuntu, but once I rebooted and removed the power, it had reset again.

I am searching online specifically for "g50-30" and specifically not for "Thinkpad", but nothing comes up so maybe it's not possible?

Does anyone know if there's a way to set a charging threshold that works on a Lenovo g50-30? Or perhaps a way I could set in on Windows and get it stuck, so that it doesn't reset when I remove the power.

Thanks.

UPDATE:

I was asked to give the output of `ls /sys/class/power_supply/BAT0`;

this is the list:

```
alarm
capacity
capacity_level
cycle_count
device
energy_full
energy_full_design
energy_now
hwmon2
manufacturer
model_name
power
power_now
present
serial_number
status
subsystem
technology
type
uevent
voltage_min_design
voltage_now
```

Comment: Not all batteries (or BIOSes) support this feature. Can you update your question to include the output of `ls /sys/class/power_supply/BAT0`? This will list the options available for your battery.

Comment: I updated the post. I don't have a ```charge_control_end_threshold```, is that not a good sign?

Comment: Some batteries have different names for the threshold setting. That said, your battery does not appear to support setting the value via the hardware APIs and, looking at the configuration options in the G50 BIOS, you do not seem to have any power management options available. You will probably need to do [something like this](https://askubuntu.com/a/518955/1222991) if you are intent on having your battery stop charging at a certain percentage.

Comment: [TLP](https://linrunner.de/tlp) 1.4 will add charge thresholds for Lenovo's Non-ThinkPads. You're welcome to participate in the [test](https://gist.github.com/linrunner/2ead4b591eed33055cf86a38ccc73949).

Comment: @linrunner Excellent, I'll give it a try. 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @linrunner mentioned in a comment, there is an [alpha test for TLP 1.4](https://gist.github.com/linrunner/2ead4b591eed33055cf86a38ccc73949) which takes advantage of the conservation mode driver on Lenovo machines. This works perfectly for me.