# Schedule a large download to resume everyday in a specific time-span of the day?

Tags: cron, wget, schedule

I want to schedule a large download to occur at night, between 12AM and 5AM. Everyday at 12AM  `wget` should automatically pick up where it left the night before, and at 5AM, it should automatically pause the download, so it can resume the following night.

How can I script this in Ubuntu? What tools do I need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A combination of an [Upstart job](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#session-job) and [a cron job](https://askubuntu.com/q/2368/158442):

First, create an Upstart job. Create a file called `~/.config/upstart/my-download.conf` containing:

```
description "My download job."
start on resume-download
stop on stop-download

respawn
respawn limit 10 5

script   
     cd /path/to/download/folder
     wget --continue uri://link/to/download    
end script
```

Now, add a cron job to start and stop this Upstart job. Run `EDITOR=gedit crontab -e` and add to the file:

```
0 0 * * * /sbin/initctl emit resume-download
0 5 * * * /sbin/initctl emit stop-download
```

You can manually start the download any time you want using:

```
initctl emit resume-download
# or
start my-download
```

And stop it any time using:

```
initctl emit stop-download
# or
stop my-download
```

---

1. Due to the `respawn` in the job, Upstart will try to restart `wget` if it exits. This can be useful if it timed out and exited at two in the morning. A limit is placed so that we don't have Upstart trying to start wget infinitely (e.g., the network is facing extended problems, the download was completed, etc.).
2. We added `initctl emit` commands in the cron job. This way, if we create more such Upstart jobs, all of them starting on this event, this single cron entry will be enough to start all of them.

Answer (score 0):

You will want to use the `--continue` [flag](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html#Download-Options) of wget and cron jobs.

You can have a [cron entry](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto) to start a script at 12AM with using timeout. See
https://serverfault.com/questions/257345/can-i-limit-the-runtime-of-a-cronjob. Or you could run another script that kills/interrupts it at 5AM.

Example for a daily script: `0 0 * * * timeout -s KILL 5h /path/to/command`

The above example will run timeout on /path/to/command at 12:00am on every day of every month and send it a KILL signal after 5 hours.

This is how a cron job is laid out:

`minute (0-59), hour (0-23, 0 = midnight), day (1-31), month (1-12), weekday (0-6, 0 = Sunday) /path/to/command`

An asterisk (*) can be used so that every instance (every hour, every weekday, every month, etc.) of a time period is used.