# How to fix auto-dim?

Tags: screen, brightness

It seems like many people have asked how to disable the auto-dim feature (System Settings -> Brightness & Lock -> Dim screen to save power). But I am having the opposite problem. I want this to work, but it often fails, i.e., the screen stays lit after the designated time has elapsed. Sometimes I have been able to fix it by logging out and then back in, but now that doesn't seem to work either. This is on a System76 Ratel Pro with an HDMI monitor. Ubuntu 16.04, kernel 4.4.0-24.

Comment: A workaround has been mentioned in here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/459591/how-to-disable-screen-dimming-in-14-04

Answer (score 0):

I looked on help.ubuntu.com and found this (again, it was someone wanting to *disable* the dimming): 
[Terminal command for checking/unchecking "Dim screen to save power"?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/565834/terminal-command-for-checking-unchecking-dim-screen-to-save-power)

So I tried:

```
gsettings get org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power idle-brightness
```

Got back 30. So, I tried this:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power idle-brightness 0
```

Now it works!