# NTP over a local network

Tags: networking, ntp

I have one server: 192.168.0.40 and 4 clients: 192.168.0.61-192.168.0.64. The clients are Raspberry Pis and so have no real time clock. Therefore the time is always wrong.

I have followed instructions [here](http://www.cameratim.com/computing/linux/time-serving) to make ntp.conf files:

server:

```
restrict default nomodify notrap noquery
restrict 127.0.0.1 

# -- CLIENT NETWORK -------
restrict 192.168.0.0 mask 255.255.255.0 nomodify notrap

# --- OUR TIMESERVERS ----- 
server 0.pool.ntp.org iburst
server 1.pool.ntp.org iburst
server 2.pool.ntp.org iburst
server 127.127.1.0

# --- NTP MULTICASTCLIENT ---

# --- GENERAL CONFIGURATION ---

# Undisciplined Local Clock.
fudge   127.127.1.0 stratum 9

# Drift file.
driftfile /var/lib/ntp/drift
broadcastdelay  0.008

# Keys file.
keys /etc/ntp/keys
```

client:

```
restrict default nomodify notrap noquery
restrict 127.0.0.1 

# -- CLIENT NETWORK -------

# --- OUR TIMESERVERS ----- 
# 192.168.1.2 is the address for my timeserver,
# use the address of your own, instead:
server 192.168.0.40 iburst
server  127.127.1.0

# --- NTP MULTICASTCLIENT ---

# --- GENERAL CONFIGURATION ---

# Undisciplined Local Clock.
fudge   127.127.1.0 stratum 12

# Drift file.
driftfile /var/lib/ntp/drift
broadcastdelay  0.008

# Keys file.
keys /etc/ntp/keys
```

However, the time on the clients is still wrong (unchanged from before). When I try connecting specifically to the server, the client cannot find it. They are 100% on the same subnet and the IP addresses are right as I can ssh no problem.

The result of ntpq -c lpeer is:

```
localhost: timed out, nothing received
***Request timed out
```

Edit:

sudo ntpdate -u 192.168.0.40 :

```
12 Dec 07:45:09 ntpdate[12815]: no server suitable for synchronization found
```

Edit 2:

The clients are on a subnet on the ethernet, and the server is connected on wifi. The system works when wifi is disabled. Is there a way around this?

Comment: Can you use `ntpdate 192.168.0.40` to force a sync?

Comment: That gets an error. I've added the result to the question.

Comment: It doesn't look as if your NTP server is listening for 192.168.0.40 has an NTP service listening. Did you restart the service?

Comment: That seems to be the answer. I had definitely restarted it before, but I think it needs to be restarted when I change the network? Post this as an answer and I'll nark it - thanks

Comment: See edit for more info on this

Comment: When the Wifi is up, can the server ping the clients?

Comment: No - this is clearly the issue. Not really sure why it should interfere like that though

Comment: Perhaps the routes are incorrectly configured.

Comment: Sorry, that was wrong. I can ping from the server to the client with wifi on but with ethernet connected, I can't access wifi. With wifi on, I can't get time on the client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NTP probably needs to be restarted if you change networking settings (SSH does as well, for example). You can test if NTP is up and listening by using `netstat` on the server and `ntpdate` on the client

On the server:

```
$ sudo netstat -unlp | grep ntp
udp        0      0 192.168.122.1:123       0.0.0.0:*                 2786/ntpd          
udp        0      0 127.0.0.1:123           0.0.0.0:*                 2786/ntpd       
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:123             0.0.0.0:*                 2786/ntpd       
udp6       0      0 fe80::4e72:b9ff:fe4:123 :::*                      2786/ntpd       
udp6       0      0 ::1:123                 :::*                      2786/ntpd       
udp6       0      0 :::123                  :::*                      2786/ntpd
```

On the client:

```
sudo ntpdate <server-ip/hostname>
```

Comment: Can this be done on boot/at regular intervals?

Comment: @user2290362 [Cron, perhaps?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/2368/how-do-i-set-up-a-cron-job). Though I still think your routes are not properly configured and that you should look into fixing them.