# Cron jobs with R scripts

Tags: cron, r

I am trying to schedule cron job for an R script.

I've read this question [How do I set cron job](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2368/how-do-i-set-up-a-cron-job) and followed suggestions from first answer.

I typed

```
crontab -e
```

In the command line and put there a line

```
*/1 * * * * /usr/bin/Rscript /home/path/scriptTorun.R
```

The crontab file was saved under name: `/tmp/crontab.6eWd50/crontab`

The execution of an R script should be append to a text file after every scheduled time (1 minute) but it is not append or there might be no execution - somewhere is my fault.

Should I try to

```
chmod +x Rscript-name
```

Any suggestions? I'm new user of the ubuntu.

An R script looks like this:

```
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)
WP <- html("http://www.wp.pl/?bigDataModule=vowpallwabbit")

Z_TYCH_LOSOWANIE <- html_nodes(WP, "[data-st-area=Sport] a[data-cluster], 
           [data-st-area=Finanse] a[data-cluster], 
           [data-st-area=Stylzycia] a[data-cluster], 
           [data-st-area=Film] a[data-cluster], 
           [data-st-area=Moto] a[data-cluster], 
           [data-st-area=Kobieta] a[data-cluster], 
           [data-st-area=Ciekawostki] a[data-cluster]") %>%
  html_attr( name = "href" )



DO_TYCH_LOSUJEMY <- html_nodes(WP, 
                                "[data-st-area=Glonews-mozaika] li:nth-child(7) a,
                                [data-st-area=Glonews-mozaika] li:nth-child(6) a,
                                [data-st-area=Glonews-mozaika-prawa] li:nth-child(1) a") %>%
  html_attr( name = "href" )


write.table( data.frame(all( DO_TYCH_LOSUJEMY %in% Z_TYCH_LOSOWANIE ), Sys.time()),
             quote=FALSE,
             append=TRUE,
            col.names=FALSE,
            row.names=FALSE, 
            file = "/home/mkosinski//bigdataincontent//Boksy//Sprawdzenie logowania kafli/output.txt" )
```

*EDIT*

I've changed the directory of an outputed file to a `/home/crontab`and removed spaces from path to the Rscript and it worked fine

Comment: Try adding `2> /tmp/cronerror` to the end of your `cron` line. That will print any error messages into the file `/tmp/cronerror`. If any errors are printed, please [edit] your question and include them.

Comment: Also, `*/1` is superfluous: `*` already means every minute.

Comment: Could you either post that as an answer or delete your question please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've changed the directory of an outputed file to a /home/crontaband removed spaces from path to the Rscript and it worked fine