# I want to write weather data via a python script twice a day to a csv file

Tags: bash, python, csv

Is this practical? How do I accomplish it?

Some barriers I've come across already:

1. I have separate scripts for weather and time. How do I format them into one comma-separated row?
2. how do I print each subsequent call to the python script(s) to a new row in the csv file?
3. I need to figure out how to schedule calls to the python or bash script twice a day.

Comment: 3: You use `cron`: http://askubuntu.com/a/2371/158442. For the other two, ask on a programming site like [so].

Answer (score 1):

1. writing / formatting.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html
http://java.dzone.com/articles/python-101-reading-and-writing

2. Same as #1 really.  Once you have the data you insert it accordingly.  You define the columns, format, etc.
3. crontab as suggested above would be easiest.
   crontab -e 
   @hourly  /path/to/script.py --arguments