# Announce the time on the hour?

Tags: gnome, cron, time, text-to-speech

On the mac there is a feature which allows you to get your computer to verbally announce the time on the hour, is there something similar on Ubuntu? That is is there a package which already does this or do I need to configure something like `say` to read out the time on the hour? And if so then how do I do that? I am running Ubuntu GNOME 15.04 with GNOME 3.16.

Comment: `date` outputs it in text. maybe you could pipe  that through a text-to-speech program?

Comment: @Wildcard: Though I would have to greatly trim and change the output of that command because it says too much, all I need and want on the hour is something like (`[time]` replaced with the hour): `It is now [time] O'clock`

Comment: See my answer, hope that can help some. You could also add something like "It is now..." before it announces the time with `sed`

Comment: Wow, this sounds annoying.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Yes, it is becoming so... :D

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You could use your crontab

1. Create a little script

   ```
    mkdir -p ~/bin
    nano ~/bin/say_hour
   ```

add the code below

```
    #!/usr/bin/env bash
    my_date=$(date +'%H:%M:%S')
    padsp espeak "$my_date"
```

and set executable rights

```
    chmod +x ~/bin/say_hour
```

2. Edit your crontab via

   ```
    crontab -e
   ```

and add the configuration below

```
    0 * * * * bin/say_hour
```

---

You can replace the `espeak` line with one of the possibilities below

```
sudo apt-get install espeak
espeak $(date +"%H:%M:%S")
espeak $(date +%T)

# Adjust speed with `-s`, in words per minute, default is 160
espeak -s 10 $(date +"%H:%M:%S")
```

or

```
sudo apt-get install festival
date +"%H:%M:%S" | festival --tts
date +%T | festival --tts
```

or

```
sudo apt-get install speech-dispatcher
spd-say $(date +"%H:%M:%S")
spd-say $(date +%T)

# Adjust speed with  (-100 .. 0 .. 100)
spd-say -r -50 $(date +%T)
```

---

- `%I` – hour (01..12) format
- `%H` – hour in (00..23) format
- `%M` – minute (00..59)
- `%S` – second (00..60)
- `%P` – period (AM/PM)
- `%T` – `HH:MM:SS` in 24 Format

---

More options via `man date`, `man espeak`, `man festival` and `man spd-say`

Comment: That doesn't work, it just wants input and gives me one of these `> `.

Comment: @A.B nice=)...Is it possible to adjust speed ?

Comment: wow @A.B working :) +1

Comment: Could you also please include in your answer how to get it to run on the hour, perhaps with a cron job as I know about them and how they work, but have never actually set one up manually.

Comment: In fact, I have a Raspberry Pi under my desk which does exactly this (and much more). It runs not the full Festival but Festival Light (`flite`). It speaks the time at the full hour, and (hh:mm) whenever I send it a Wake-on-Lan packet. I set it to speak slightly slower (`set Duration_stretch=1.3`) to get a more pleasant tone of voice.

Comment: A 2022 update/supplement to @A.B. 's answer: spd-say seems to be the preferred/default TTS tool. However, it requires XDG_RUNTIME_DIR to be set, yet cron does not do this for you. See this nice solution: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/61778  . With that at the top of your shell script, spd-say should successfully run when invoked by crond. Side note: I found no mention of XDG_RUNTIME_DIR in the manpages for spd-say and speech-dispatcher, nor in the output of the "silent" spd-say call.

Answer (score 5):

This gives you the time in speech (thanks to kos for providing better syntax) :

First install `say` , which is found in `gnustep-gui-runtime`:

```
sudo apt-get install gnustep-gui-runtime
```

Then run it.

24-hour mode:

```
say "$(date +%R)"
```

12-hour mode

```
say "$(date +%I:%M%p)"
```

Comment: Could you also please include in your answer how to get it to run on the hour, perhaps with a cron job as I know about them and how they work, but have never actually set one up manually.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to do that @ParanoidPanda . If someone else does, they can post it as a comment and I'll include it in my post

Comment: @ParanoidPanda http://askubuntu.com/questions/2368/how-do-i-set-up-a-cron-job ;)

Comment: @Wildcard: A.B. has included it in his answer so you could probably just take it from there or read what kos commented. :)

Comment: @ParanoidPanda A.B. has the accepted answer, so it's not really that important

Comment: @Wildcard: Ok, I have done that.