# How to turn off the network connection

Tags: 14.04, networking, internet, connection

I'm looking for a little help. I was kinda wondering how to turn off network connection for some time period.

My question is - how to set up (for example) "Network connection is available only between 5pm and 6pm?"

Thanks

Comment: The simplest approach which I can think of right now would be to use  `/etc/rc.local` file to disable  `network-manager` service at boot, then when use `at` command to schedule that service being started at 5pm, and finally add another command that kills the service at 6 pm.  The network icon won't show up for the user. Limitation, though, is that if the user has access to terminal, they could start the service manually .  There's other options too, but I'll need to think about this question a bit. Perhaps others here can provide a faster and easier solution

Answer (score 0):

You could use *crontab* to run the scripts at scheduled times. If computer is not running all the time, you may need to combine it with *anacron* and/or `/etc/rc.local`.

The commands to enable/disable network connections are:

```
nmcli c up id "<connection id>"
nmcli c down id "<connection id>"
```

You can look for connections and there ids in the `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/`.

Answer (score 0):

I think your looking for a cron job.

```
edit /etc/rc.local
```

and add the following line `sudo service network-manager stop` so that networking will be disabled at boot.

next you would want to add a cron job that will start networking at 5pm

```
crontab -e
```

`00 17 * * 0 sudo service network-manager start`

and add another job that will stop networking at 6pm

```
crontab -e
```

`00 18 * * 0 sudo service network-manager stop`

[How do I set up a cron job?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2368/how-do-i-set-up-a-cron-job)

[CronHowto wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto)