# Schedule tomcat7 restart on Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS

Tags: restart, tomcat, tomcat7, schedule

I have an issue with Tomcat 7 on my Ubuntu machine.

I'm still a rookie in this, but it seems that restarting the `tomcat7` service fixes the issue. I would like to make a scheduled task on the machine to restart `tomcat7` every 2 days.

For now I use `sudo /etc/init.d/tomcat7 restart`, is there an easy way to implement this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I set up a Cron job?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/2368/how-do-i-set-up-a-cron-job)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `cron` package is the normal tool for scheduling events on your system. You can put actions into your user's crontab with the `crontab -e` command. Although as you need to use sudo to execute the init.d script, this won't work unless you've set up sudo usage with no password for that command.

My suggestion is that you edit the root crontab, by doing `sudo crontab -e`, and enter the line:

```
30 6 */2 * * /usr/bin/service tomcat7 restart
```

This will restart tomcat7 at 6:30am every 2 days. If you want a different time, just alter the first two numbers. The command probably looks different to what you'd expect, but in 14.04 the correct way to use scripts in `/etc/init.d` is to use the `service` command. More information on cron usage can be found [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a cron job for this. Create a shell script with these:

```
#!/bin/sh
/etc/init.d/tomcat7 restart
```

Then set up a job in the `crontab`:

```
0 0 */2 * * root my_script.sh
```

This will run the script at midnight, every two days.

---

This will "solve" your immediate problem. However I suggest to fix your application running on Tomcat, it is hardly ready for production, if it needs restarts like this.