# Running cron job on every Monday, Wednesday & Friday of a week

Tags: cron

I want to know how I can create a cron job to run a `.sh` file automatically on every Monday, Wednesday & Friday @ night 12 am USA PST?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I set up a Cron job?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/2368/how-do-i-set-up-a-cron-job)

Answer (score 2):

It can be done in  one line too

0 0 0 0 1,3,5 /pathofscript/

Answer (score -1):

Create THREE cron table entries, one running your script Monday at 0000, one running it Wednesday at 0000, and one running it Friday at 0000. Or schedule script execution for 0000 EVERY day, and have the script exit quietly on Tuesday, Thursday, Saturday and Sunday.

Remember that the "Cron environment" differs from your current environment (different `$PATH`, `$DISPLAY` not defined, possible different execution path in `~/.bashrc`, ...). Read `man 8 cron;man 5  crontab`. Initially log start/stop messages to a directory you **know** exists, like `/tmp`. If you are not logged in at 0000 M,W,F, your encrypted `HOME` directory will not be available.