# How to do a monthly system backup

Tags: 14.04, server, backup, cron

I want to create an automatic monthly backup on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS - Server Ed., with the following command:

```
$ tar -cvpz --exclude=/bckupftp --exclude=/ser --exclude=/proc --exclude=/lost+found --exclude=/mnt --exclude=/sys / | split -d -b 750m - /bckupftp/backup20160422-041400.tar.gz
```

I added a date and time in the backup filename. It would be nice if this could be set to the actual-backup-date/time automatically. For a `cronjob` set to run on May 01, 2016 at 1am, the backup-filename would be: `/bckupftp/backup20160501-010000.tar.gz`.

***Can somebody help me set up a `cronjob` for this command ?***  Thanks, Kevin

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I set up a Cron job?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/2368/how-do-i-set-up-a-cron-job)

Comment: @DavidFoerster: Yes, I would second your flagging this as a dupe, if I could .

Comment: You probably want to exclude `/dev`, `/tmp`, and `/run` as well. Backing up `/boot` or `/var` doesn't make a lot of sense either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To set up the cronjob for yr present non-root user, do in terminal:

```
$ crontab -e
```

The above will open yr (non-root) user's `crontab` with his/her default editor.

Alternatively, to do so for the root `crontab`, but with yr present (presumably non-root) user environment parameters (default editor, etc.):

```
$ sudo -i crontab -e
```

In yr opened `crontab`, enter a new line:

```
0 01 01 * * /bin/tar -cvpz --exclude=/bckupftp --exclude=/ser --exclude=/proc --exclude=/lost+found --exclude=/mnt --exclude=/sys / | /usr/bin/split -d -b 750m - /bckupftp/backup$(/bin/date +\%Y\%m\%d-\%H\%M\%S).tar.gz
```

*(I did not check the validity of yr `tar` cmd.)*

Note that:

- `crontab` uses a 24-hour clock, military style: `15` means 3pm, `03` means 3am, etc.
- the above `cron` entry runs at 01:00 o'clock the first day of every month. In terminal , do: `man crontab` for more info on crontab formats.
- in `crontab`, it's a good habit to prefix cmds with their full path. To find the full path of any non-built-in cmd, do in terminal `$ which <cmd>`.  Thus the `tar` cmd becomes `/bin/tar`, `split` becomes `/usr/bin/split`, etc..
- as soon as you save the newly edited `crontab`, the `cron` job becomes effective. No need to reboot, log out and back in, or restart whatever service.
- when saving yr bckup file(s), the time stamp has the following format YYYYMMDD-HHMMSS.  If you need it to be more precise, try replacing `%S` with `%s` in yr `crontab` entry.
- I am certain (meaning "with 100% probability") you can find all the above explained in great details in AU, SE at large as well as in other fora. Remember that *[StartPage](https://www.startpage.com/)* is yr friend.

Answer (score 0):

Create a file: `/etc/cron.monthly/backups.sh`
make it executable by: `$ chmod +x /etc/cron.monthly/backups.sh`

to tidy it up, create a variable:

```
DATE=`date +%Y.%m.%d-%H.%M.%S`                   # eg. 2016.04.22-13.01.59
```

And then reference your command above with:
`/bckupftp/backup${DATE}.tar.gz`

It would produce a file similar to:
`/bckupftp/backup2016.04.22-13.01.59.tar.gz`

Feel free to remove dots to your liking and needs.

Comment: Welcome to AU ! Please look up formatting guidelines (https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/89/style-guide-for-questions-and-answers) on this site, as well as this answer (https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/13828/formatting-guideline-convention-for-program-names-commands-strings-values/13839#13839) by Eliah Kagan. Doing so will make yr answers and questions even greater. :-)