# How to: automatically restart Ubuntu server every 6 months as a scheduled task?

Tags: reboot, automation, schedule

I have a mail server in my environment and I never touched it (someone configured it for me at first) since a few days ago when everything stopped working and I was unable to receive any emails. The error was "Kernel Panic" and I had to reboot the server. Someone looked at it and decided that the high uptime caused this. I want to implement a scheduled task to restart the server every 6 months on a Saturday at midnight. Is this possible? Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I set up a Cron job?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/2368/how-do-i-set-up-a-cron-job)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can configure a cron job for this task.

```
00 12 01 */6 * bash -c "reboot"
```

Will reboot the computer every 6 months at 12:00

Comment: And if I use 24h format I need to run it like this? 00 00 01 */6 * bash -c "reboot" ?

Comment: The second value is given in hours - values 0 to 23 are valid. maybe this cheat sheet will help you understand http://www.pc-freak.net/images/crontab-execute-cron-jobs-every-second-on-linux-cron-logo.png

Comment: Thanks. I'll try to set it up and see. Is there any way to test if it works? Like trigger it somehow?

Comment: Set it to reboot every 10 minutes. This will give you a short time to wait for testing but enough to remove the crontab entry again. Also see murus comment on your question.

Comment: Alright, cheers. I'll try. One more question: */6 this part means that every year in June and December the server will reboot, right? What if I want to reboot it in 6 months starting today? does that work like that (e.g. from when you set it up? or does it calculate the months of the year as I said above?)