# Python script in CRON is not running in AWS ubuntu 14.04 instance

Tags: 14.04, python, cron, aws

I want to schedule a CRON job into AWS Ubuntu instance. I have a simple cron sample like the following:

```
import pandas as greatPanda
import pprint
import uuid

df = greatPanda.read_csv('/home/soumik/appTornado/di/ABP/df.csv')

pprint.pprint(df)
name = '/home/soumik/appTornado/di/ABP/df_'+str(uuid.uuid4())+'.csv'
df.to_csv(name,index=False)
```

And I have set the CRON like the following with `crontab -e` into terminal:

```
*/1 * * * * python /home/ubuntu/ABP/abp_backend_processing/cronSample.py > /home/ubuntu/ABP/abp_backend_processing/cronlog.txt
```

The sample code has been run into my local machine with proper CRON functionality but can not find any luck into AWS instance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I set up a Cron job?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/2368/how-do-i-set-up-a-cron-job)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To set up the cronjob for the user you have logged in for follow this steps

1. log into the ssh console
2. Open the crontab file by typing crontab -e
3. close the file with changes you want to make. In your case the syntax is right.
4. Once you close the file you can see that 'new crontab is installing' message
   you are done.

Answer (score 0):

I think your Cron service not started.
Try:

```
service crond start
```

You can check Cron service status with:

```
service crond status
```

Make sure your script file has execute permission.