# I can't install gnome schedule on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, cron, schedule

I would like to install gnome-schedule in my recent Ubuntu 16.04 but I can't find the how. It is not in ubuntu software and if I type `sudo apt-get install gnome-schedule`, I get it's not found. I would like to use it because I find it quick and easy to use. I've been looking for alternatives but instead of "when" which I don't like, I can't find anything else, so help is welcome.

Comment: gnome-schedule has been deprecated. Here the the August 2017 solution for Ubuntu 16.04 LTS:  https://askubuntu.com/questions/942401/how-to-control-cron-in-ubuntu-16-04-lts

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`gnome-schedule` is indeed not in the official Ubuntu repositories for Ubuntu 16.04.

However, at https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-schedule/+bug/1576060/comments/23, Kartik (kartik-arora95) has kindly compiled a `.deb` package for version 2.3.0 of Gnome Schedule that is reportedly working for Ubuntu 16.04. Download the `.deb` package provided at the aforementioned link and then install it using:

```
sudo dpkg -i gnome-schedule_2.3.0-0ubuntu16.04_amd64.deb
```

Comment: Normal cron commands still work.  crontab -e is how you set up and manage jobs, and crontab -l will list your jobs.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It has been very usefull. I've installed and it worked perfectly. Thank you!!

Comment: Why had Gnome-Scheudule been dropped?

Comment: sudo apt-get install librarian0 scrollkeeper rarian-compat at

Answer (score 1):

Used gnome-schedule for many years in many earlier versions of Ubuntu. Nice one. Ubuntu 16.04 not having gnome-schedule is highly inconvenient. A verified source is here: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/xenial/+package/gnome-schedule

You will require to compile from sources.

Comment: I wrote an answer that details how to install it using a `.deb` package provided by a user at `gnome-schedule`'s Launchpad repository. See if it works for you.

Answer (score 1):

I have compiled gnome-scheduler for 16.04 by editing the Ubuntu source package for Natty a bit. Here you go https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-schedule/+bug/1576060/comments/35