# Cannot install gnome-schedule from official Ubuntu repositories

Tags: software-center, gnome-schedule

I am supposed to be able to install `gnome-schedule` using:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-schedule
```

Unfortunately, this returns:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package gnome-schedule
```

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.  According to [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/785657/i-cant-install-gnome-schedule-on-ubuntu-16-04), I should download some code, compile, and then install.  It seems as thought for such a basic program it should come from the official Ubuntu repositories.  (I, for one, am always concerned about installing third party software from unverified sources.)

Interestingly enough, when I try from Ubuntu Software Center, I can see `gnome-schedule' showing the item but there is no button to install.  Also, when I click on <kbd>More Info</kbd> it says Not Found (see pictures below).  Of course, I cannot see it on synaptic either.

How can we get to have this added to the official repositories?

[image: Ubuntu Software Center: Schedule]
[image: Ubuntu Software Center: Schedule error]

Comment: Here is a Q&A on the official party line regarding this issue:  https://askubuntu.com/questions/942401/how-to-control-cron-in-ubuntu-16-04-lts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can see here, gnome-schedule is no longer part of the official sources from version 16.04 :
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-schedule/+bug/1576060

But you can manually download and compile the code.

```
 $ git clone https://github.com/GNOME/gnome-schedule.git
 $ pushd gnome-schedule
 $ ./autogen.sh --prefix=/usr/local
 $ make
 $ make install
```

https://github.com/GNOME/gnome-schedule

Comment: Thanks.  I tried and after installing `git` and running the first like I get an error saying: 

`git clone git://git.gnome.org/git/gnome-schedule`

`Cloning into 'gnome-schedule'... `
fatal: Could not read from remote repository. <br>

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists. </code>

Comment: try the new URL I've put

Comment: Yes, Ubuntu has deprecated this GUI software - but regular crontab commands work fine.  crontab -e is the one to know.  Also, crontab -l will list your current jobs.  Here is what Ubuntu has to say about it:  https://askubuntu.com/questions/942401/how-to-control-cron-in-ubuntu-16-04-lts