# Delete files older then x days, from the day when they moved into random folder

Tags: delete

I run Ubuntu 14.04 as file server for windows clients. Clients have mapped network shared folder to work with. When they delete files from that folder, files goes to ".recycle". I wanted to delete files older then x days. I used autotrash command:

```
autotrash -d 30 -T /home/etc/.recycle
```

but it tells me that .recycle doesn't contain info file:

```
Can not find trash information directory. Make sure you have at least GNOME 2.24
```

I was looking at: `/home/etc/.recycle/info`

Latest Gnome is installed and result are same. I understand that app can't read info when files moved into .recycle. I can use command: `find /path/to/files* -mtime +5 -exec rm {} \;` but when files move into .recycle they keep last modification date, not date when they move into folder.

Can I create info file? Is there any solution how can I delete files older then x days from a day when files moved into some folder?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the following script to be ran every X days ([using `cron`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2368/how-do-i-set-up-a-cron-job/2371#2371)):

```
#!/bin/bash

cd /home/etc/recycle_old           #Deletes old trash
rm -r ./*

cd /home/etc
mv -r ./recycle ./recycle_old      #Moves new trash to "old"-folder
```

It works like this:

**1.** There are 2 folders, `recycle` (which is already given) for the "recent" deleted files, and `recycle_old` for the "old" files.

**2.** Every X days all the content from `recycle_old` is deleted and replaced with the "recent" content from `recycle`

If you want to delete files older than a month, simply move the script to `/etc/cron.monthly`. If you want something more specific, check out [how to set a cronjob](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2368/how-do-i-set-up-a-cron-job/2371#2371).

Comment: Thank you for script.
As always simplest solution is the best :) This helps me alot. Thx again.